# About memoir and titlesec incompatibility

Tags: sectioning, memoir, titlesec, incompatibility

In page 2 of the `titlesec` documentation, Javier Bezos writes

> `titlesec` works with the standard classes and with many others,
>   including the AMS ones, and it runs smoothly with `hyperref`.
>   Unfortunately, it is not compatible with `memoir`, which provides its
>   own tools with a limited subset of the features available in `titlesec`.

I don't use the `memoir` document class so I am not familiar with its features, but I've made a few simple tests (really few and simple) using it together with `titlesec` and couldn't detect any problems. To what extent can `titlesec` be safely used with `memoir`? Which exactly are the incompatibilities mentioned?

Comment: See this answer here [Examples of styles for section headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/examples-of-styles-for-section-headings-with-memoir/8806#8806) for a parallel quote from the `memoir` manual.  As I understand it, they're not really incompatible, but you can't really mix and match their respective ways of redefining the sectioning commands.

Comment: **memoir** defines sectioning commands with *two* optional arguments and this will be lost with **titlesec**.

Comment: @egreg: but something like 
`\usepackage{titlesec}\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\itshape}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}` will still allow using the two optional arguments of `\chapter`.

Comment: As long as you consistently use _only_ `titlesec` commands for specifying titles, you should have no problems with `memoir`. But you cannot mix and match.

Comment: I have brought this thing up with the memoir maintainer and asked to replace memoir's rather limited algorithms with those of titlesec. Unfortunately, he wouldn't listen... The titlesec way of doing things is far superior to the may memoir does it. But I still use memoir since it is getting a long way in the right direction.

Comment: Exactly when have you brought this up? But, no I would not change it. I do not like making memoir depend on other packages. Plus as far as I know you loose memoir features by using titlesec. Yes it is harder to use, but I still find it more flexible.

Comment: @daleif Yah! Very relieved that I should be able to keep using Memoir. For some reason, I'm allergic to `titlesec`. I have discovered no case in which it is not easier to do without `titlesec` what I was trying to do with it - usually *much* easier. Even where I initially wrote code with `titlesec`, I've eventually had to eliminate it when debugging. Plus, you can get Memoir sections to play nicely with microtypography (like the standard classes), but not `titlesec`. I have no fix for `titlesec` sectioning, but my fix works fine with Memoir.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For chapters the incompatibility is not evident, as `\titleformat{\chapter}...` will redefine `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`. However

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

will redefine `\section` in such a way that the second optional argument is not accepted; indeed

```
\section[section toc][section head]{section title}
```

will produce the correct entry in the table of contents, but

> **1.1** [
>     section header]section title

in the document in contrast to what **memoir**'s documentation advertises.