# Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec, incompatibility

This is a complementary question to [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012/about-memoir-and-titlesec-incompatibility). The [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manual states (p. 2) that the package

> [...] works with the standard classes and with many others, including
>   the AMS ones [...] Unfortunately, it is not compatible with
>   `memoir`[...]

The manual does not mention the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes. So, can `titlesec` and `KOMA-Script` be used together without problems, or are there some incompatibilities (or at least situations where special care must be taken)?

Comment: In general: [What packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73248).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've never used this combination myself, but a search with your favorite engine should show you that there are some incompatibilities, e.g. (all in German):

- [Paket `titlesec` und KOMA-Skript-Befehl `\setindexpreamble`](http://meinews.niuz.biz/paket-t505606.html) (it was originally a usenet post, but [the archived Google groups version is broken](http://groups.google.de/group/de.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/ba3488418a358386); with an interesting answer of Markus Kohm, the author of `KOMA-Script`)
- [`\setpartpreamble` funktioniert nicht mit `titlesec`?!](http://www.golatex.de/setpartpreamble-funktioniert-nicht-mit-titlesec-t7260.html)
- [`titlesec` und `scrpage` 2](http://www.komascript.de/node/795) (on Markus Kohm's website with answer of him)
- [Abstand Gliederungsziffer <-> Überschrift](http://www.komascript.de/node/732) (again on komascript.de)
- [Paket `titlesec` und `\dictum` aus KOMA-Script](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=63900)
- [Platz vor und nach Sections anpassen](http://komascript.de/node/1789) (again on Markus Kohm's website with answer of him)

See this answer of mine for an additional observed incompatibility: [Can't shift/position \chapter with titlesec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51861/9237).

#### Update in beginning of 2014

With recently published version 3.12 of KOMA-Script one will get a warning when compiling a document with `titlesec`:

> ```
> Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
> (scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
> (scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use the package only
> (scrartcl)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
> (scrartcl)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
> (scrartcl)              the extended optional argument of the section
> (scrartcl)              commands .
> ```

Comment: Months later … a short explanation: When I read lockstep’s question, I could darkly remember that there was some months ago a question in the usenet in `de.comp.text.tex` with an remarkable answer of Markus Kohm. By searching for that I found the linked questions and answers.

Answer (score 19):

The `KOMA-Script` classes provide the commands `\addpart`, `\addchap`, and `\addsec` which will start a new unnumbered part/chapter/section that is nevertheless added to the ToC. If you combine `KOMA-Script`, `titlesec`, and `hyperref`, be sure to add a `\phantomsection` in the `after` argument of a `\section` redefined with `\titleformat` -- otherwise, the ToC links of `\addsec` will point to the wrong page.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{titlesec}
% Incorrect ToC link to \addsec
% \titleformat{\section}{\Huge\sffamily}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
% Correct ToC link to \addsec
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\sffamily}{\thesection}{0.5em}{\phantomsection}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{foo}

\clearpage

\addsec{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With an uptodate KOMA-Script version the `\phantomsection` can be removed from the example.

Comment: @esdd I have not looked in the code, it might be rather "with an uptodate hyperref". Indeed, I think that at some point `\phantomsection` became superfluous when using `\addcontentsline` for section or chapter. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, `titlesec` (in version 2.10.1) is fully incompatible with KOMA script. The following minimal example doesn't even compile anymore:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
  \section{one}
\end{document}
```

My system shows the following errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.5   \section{one}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.5   \section{one}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.5   \section{one}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.5   \section{one}

?
```

Comment: I have the same problem.