# remove boldface from chapter titles, section and subsection names

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bold

How is it possible to remove the boldface  from chapter titles, section and subsection names? I have found the following code for sections, but I can't find a way for chapters and subsections.

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
 {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
 {\normalfont\Large}}
 \makeatother
```

**EDIT**: Be sure to check the answer I provided in addition to Tobi's and Werner's answers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: What document class are you using? If it's one of the KOMA classes (scr...) then you can use    \setkomafont{sectioning}{ instructions } to change the behavior. \normalfont in the argument would should take the bold away then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the class you are using there are different more or less easy ways.

If you use<sup>*</sup> KOMA-Script (which is recommended especially for german texts) you can change the `disposition` font element:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% analogus to book class

\setkomafont{disposition}{\mdseries\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) may helps

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[md]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

The `titlesec` package would work with KOMA-Script too …

<sub>* A full working [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would have showed the class so I don’t have to guess ;-)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your response.I just tried the code and it works, but I'd rather stick to the standard book class.

Comment: @niels: See my edit. I added an example using `titlesec` which works with the standard classes as well.

Comment: @Tobi: There are some incompatibilities between `titlesec` and KOMa-Script, see [About KOMA-Script and titlesec incompatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/about-koma-script-and-titlesec-incompatibility).

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks, I didn’t know that. But I never had problems with this combination in the past …

Answer (score 6):

You could also patch the standard [`book` document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) commands using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\bfseries}{\relax}{}{}% Non-bold \chapter name
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\bfseries}{\relax}{}{}% Non-bold \chapter title
\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\relax}{}{}% Non-bold \section
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\relax}{}{}% Non-bold \subsection
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter} This is a chapter.
\section{First section} This is a section.
\subsection{First subsection} This is a subsection.
\end{document}
```

The reason for patching `\@makechapterhead` twice is because the name (Chapter) and title is separately typeset in `\bfseries`.

Comment: How does `etoolbox` differentiate between the two `\@makechapterhead` patches?

Comment: @Tobi: `etoolbox` patches only the first equal command.

Comment: @Tobi: It patches the first command corresponding to the given string. Therefore, two calls with the same arguments will patch the second occurrence of the same string. This is the case with `\@makechapterhead`, since `\bfseries` is used twice - once for the chapter name (`\chaptername \thechapter`) and once for the chapter title.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, Werner: Thanks for this explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is actually a comment on Werner's answer. Although initially I accepted and used Tobi's answer, in the end I decided to use the method described in Werner's answer.

I noticed some interesting things I'd like to share. It all started when I decided to leave chapter titles (Chapter 1,2...) bold but remove boldface from chapter names (Introduction, ...).

Here is an excerpt from `book.cls`

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The first `\bfseries` refers to chapter title (Chapter 1,2...) and the second to chapter name.

So:

If I simultaneously use

```
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
```

neither chapter title nor name should be bold. And indeed this is what happens.

If I use only

```
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge\bfseries }{\huge }
```

the chapter title shouldn't be boldface but the chapter name should be. And indeed this is what happens.

**BUT**

If I use

```
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries}{\Huge }{}{}
```

I expect the chapter title to be boldface and the chapter name to be non-boldface. Instead both elements are boldface!!!!

Somehow the first (refering to chapter title) `\bfseries` also affects the chapter name (I don't know why but I guess people that know more about latex syntax could explain).

In order to bypass this behavior, I had to limit the scope of that first `\bfseries`. So I used

```
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{\huge{\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}}{}{}
```

(note the extra pair of curly brackets inserted to enclose `\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter`)

After this patch then
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries}{\Huge }{}{}

works as expected.