# article document class: remove boldface from all titles

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bold

My question relates to [remove boldface from chapter titles, section and subsection names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38331/remove-boldface-from-chapter-titles-section-and-subsection-names) on removing boldface from `chapter` titles, `section` and `subsection` names, the difference being that I need to remove boldface from `chapter` titles, `section` and `subsection` names from an `article` class document.

Comment: Or the simpler `sectsty` package that allows to say `\allsectionsfont{\normalfont}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
   \allsectionsfont{\normalfont}
   \begin{document}
   \section{A section}
   \subsection{A subsection}
   \subsubsection{A subsubsection}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This provides a clean and understandable input. Another reference using this approach is available in [Is it possible to change text color for all headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68376/5764)
2. A patch of the section header printing macro `\@sect` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
     {#6}% <search>
     {#6\normalfont}% <replace>
     {}{}% <success><failure>
   \makeatother
   \begin{document}
   \section{A section}
   \subsection{A subsection}
   \subsubsection{A subsubsection}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This is a little obscure. The sixth argument to `\@sect` stems from the same argument to `\@startsection` - the default section-producing macro in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). For example, here's an extract for `\section`, which provides as argument six `\normalfont\Large\bfseries`:

   ```
   \newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                      {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
   ```

   The patch inserts `\normalfont` after *every* sixth argument, regardless of the section being produced.

Both options produce the output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package

[image: screenshot]

A complete MWE follows. The code is commented which should explain the details- let me know if you need further details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}   % customizing sections
\usepackage{lipsum}

% custom section
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large}% format applied to label+text
{\thesection}% label
{5pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
{}% before the title body
[]% after the title body

% custom subsection
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large}% format applied to label+text
{\thesubsection}% label
{5pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
{}% before the title body
[]% after the title body

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{My subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```