# Can't shift/position \chapter with titlesec?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, titlesec

Somehow I my attempt to change the placement of \chapter seems not to work. I would like to that my chaptertitle begins right at the top of the page. Do I need to change the plain pagestyle?

```
\documentclass[paper=15cm:23cm, headinclude=true, numbers=enddot, draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}   
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{% 
\normalfont\sffamily\scshape} 
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{} 
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}

%Position of Chaptertitle
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This first chapter}
Hi there.
\end{document}
```

Comment: First: It would be really better, if you’d provide a _full_ MWE! Second: As you live in Berlin and have a German comment in your code I suppose this answer of mine could be helpful: [About KOMA-Script and titlesec incompatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36310/9237).

Comment: OMG, the most obvious `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` I’ve overlooked. What are `tocloft` and `etoolbox` for? If not needed here, leave them out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define both the `\titleformat` and the `\titlespacing`, then you can have complete control:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}

%Position of Chaptertitle
\titleformat{\chapter}
            {\usekomafont{chapter}}
            {\thechapter.\hspace{1em}}
            {0pt}
            {}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This first chapter}
Hi there.
\end{document}
```

I am not sure at the moment why you cannot just use `\titlespacing`, but it probably has to do with the way `KOMA` redefines the section styles.  Note that you do not need to use the *advanced interface* – it suffices to issue any of the of `titlesec` commands that actually touch the format.  Thus, you can also use the *easy setup*, specifying one of the class options `rm`, `sf`, `tt`, `md`, `bf`, `up`, `it`, `sl`, `sc` as described in the manual:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}

% This is optional when the easy-setup is used:
%\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\chapter}{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}}

% Position of Chapter title
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This first chapter}
Hi there.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I deleted the redundant `\usepackage{disposition}`. I could have deleted alternatively the more specific `\usepackage{chapter}` as well.

Comment: @Speravir I assume you meant to say ``\usekomafont{disposition}``.  Are you sure this conforms with the default KOMA behaviour?  The English documentation seems to indicates that both ``disposition`` and ``chapter`` should be used to emulate the default behaviour. (Maybe this is a translation ambiguity?)

Comment: Yes, I meant this one. `disposition` is the generic element for several other elements, which use it’s definition. Whether `\usekomafont{disposition}` is needed, depends of a redefinition by `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont` of disposition or a dependent element. Here inside `\usekomafont{chapter}` the whole _default definition_ of `disposition` is already included, so it could be removed. (Side remark: There is an alias for `disposition` named `sectioning`, where I as a not natural English speaker understand much better, what it is meant for.)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine.

I introduced `titlesec`s command `\titleformat`, which is made for such efforts.

Notes:

- I’ve added a font package (`kpfonts` is only an example, but an excellent), because without that your definition for the pagehead didn’t work.
- I’d use the pagestyle `scrheadings`, so I’ve added the according command.
- Together with KOMA-Script it is recommended to use the package’s own font switch commands also for `scrpage2` influenced font attributes (see KOMA-Script manual, section for `scrpage2`).
- On the other hand this KOMA-Script own font switch for “chapter” does not work here with `\titleformat`; it seems, it’s another [KOMA-Script and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/about-koma-script-and-titlesec-incompatibility/). But there is cure by the use of `\usekomafont` inside the `\titleformat` definition (thanks to mforbes for this idea). Note, that the documentclass option `headings=big`, which also should set the chaptertitle to `\huge`, does  **not** work either!
- I’ve changed your absolut values for title separation into relative ones: `\baselineskip` and `em` instead of `pt`.

  ```
    \documentclass[%
    paper=15cm:23cm,%
    headinclude=true,%
    numbers=enddot,%
    draft,%
  ]{scrbook}%
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

  \usepackage{kpfonts}

  \usepackage[ngerman,latin]{babel}% option "latin" only because of use of "lipsum"

  \usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% no numbering in the pagehead
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
  %%% works, but is not recommended together with KOMA-Script:
  %\renewcommand*{\headfont}{
  %\normalfont\sffamily\scshape}
  %%% This is the recommended way:
  \setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily\scshape}

  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\huge}

  \titleformat{\chapter}
              {\usekomafont{chapter}}
              {\thechapter.}
              {1em}
              {\filleft}

  %Position of Chaptertitle
  \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-3\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}%

  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}

  \chapter{Lipsum Lapsum Lepsum Lopsum Lupsum Lypsum}
  \lipsum[1-5]

  \chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
  \lipsum[6-10]

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: I meant something different. But Thanks!

Comment: I noticed. Please see my updated answer. I hope the other information is also useful for you.