# Reducing spacing after headings

Tags: spacing, sectioning, paragraphs, line-spacing

I've searched many sites but I couldn't get any answer. Here is this mystical question:

**How can i reduce the spacing after headings?**

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
 \usepackage[overload]{textcase} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\addto\extrasturkish{\uccode`i=\string"9D \lccode`I=\string"19 }
\addto\noextrasturkish{\uccode`i=`I \lccode`I=`i }

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{#1}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

My actual purpose is to set line spacing 1.5 lines. This is a MS Word template that I must use for my project report. When I use `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` with  `\linespread{1.5}` the gap between section headings and paragraphs are huge, so huge it is funny. If I don't use `\linespread{1.5}` the lines are not spreading as expected. If I don't use `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` this time there is no spacing between paragraphs.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You've loaded the `titlesec` package- it provides the command `\titlespacing` which has the format

```
\titlespacing{command}{left spacing}{before spacing}{after spacing}[right]
```

From the `titlesec` [package](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)

```
% Spacing: how to read {12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
% 12pt is what we would like the spacing to be.
% plus 4pt means that TeX can stretch it by at most 4pt.
% minus 2pt means that TeX can shrink it by at most 2pt.
% This is one example of the concept of, 'glue', in TeX.
```

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation and good answer. I've changed 0pt to -5 pt and this really looks good.

Comment: Do you know how the gap between "1" and "Section" is set?  The `\titlespacing` parameters don't seem to adjust that.

Comment: @steven: I believe that titlespacing is vertical space only; not sure of the official way to tweak the gap you describe, but I usually use an ugly hack involving titleformat and hspace

Comment: Found it.  In the definition of `\@sect`, one will find `\begingroup #6{\@hangfrom {\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}\interlinepenalty\@M #8\@@par}\endgroup`.  A kern can be added after `\@svsec`...  Actually, that's close, but it's more complicated than that, to account for * sections.  But I'll get there.

Comment: But even better, `\@seccntformat` is defined as `{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}`  The `\quad` represents the gap of interest and can be changed.

Comment: Nice one. Works fine. But it removes the numbering of the section headings. Is there any way to bring back the section numbers ?

Comment: I never understood what is the use of `plus` and `minus` in such commands could you kindly give a link where to understand their purpose?

Comment: That is great but it does not change the space between section title and the starting point when I change first number (12)

Comment: it might be worth noting that the ``titlesec`` package must be loaded after the ``sectsty`` package (the latter can be used to change the color of section titles) otherwise it has no effect.

Answer (score 34):

You can use the `\titlespacing` command from the `titlesec` package. For example:

```
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
```

See [titlesec.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for more options.

Comment: I found this suggestion work the best for markdown with YMAL header rendered by pandoc

Comment: Does `\parskip` include the "glue" that the author of `titlesec` describes? There's no mention of ± anything in the documentation. Why would you use `\parskip` instead of the more specific lengths that @cmhughes advocates?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `setspace`, then mixing it with your own `\linespread{1.5}` is probably not a good idea.

Try to delete the line about `\linespread` and use instead

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

The package documentation says that it does more than just change line spread: it also take care of skips before and after headings, displays, etc. - the things you say you need.

Answer (score 3):

To control **each space individually**, it is possible to use `\vspace{-5mm}` or `\vspace{-1em}` or `\vspace{-1cm}`.

Follow a working example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{geometry}
     \geometry{a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=20mm, top=20mm, }
    
    \title{Space handling in \LaTeX}
    \author{Yuri Gelsleichter}
    \date{December 2020}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{\huge Increase \Large space between headings and text}
    
    \subsection{Using (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{5mm\}})}
    \vspace{5mm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. 

    \subsection{Using (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{1em\}})}
    \vspace{1em}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. 

    \subsection{Using (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{0.7cm\}})}
    \vspace{0.7cm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. 

    \vspace{2cm}
    \hrulefill
    \vspace{2cm}

    \section{\huge Decrease \Large space between headings and text}
    
    \subsection{Using (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{-4mm\}})}
    \vspace{-4mm}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    \subsection{Using (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{-1em\}})}
    \vspace{-1em} 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    \subsection{Using (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{-0.4cm\}})}
    \vspace{-0.4cm}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you provide to a complete full code starting from `\documentclass ..(packages)...\begin{document} ....\end{document}`.

Comment: @YuriGelsleichter I added an image of the output. For next time, it can easily be done when editing the post by clicking on the image icon. If you're not sure how to do it when you write or edit a post, you can click on the question mark on the upper right corner of the box, and more details will appear.

Comment: Hi @Sebastiano, thanks very much! I was not aware that I could add image yet

Comment: @YuriGelsleichter Welcome into the TeX.SE. community again and all the best.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a KOMA-Script based document class (e.g. `scrartcl`), you can't (or rather: shouldn't) use the `titlesec` package as it is [incompatible with KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/128658).

Instead, you can follow the approach given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233428/128658), which suggests to use the `\RedeclareSectionCommand` macro. A minimal example of this could look like this (copied from the linked answer):

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=half% inserts additional space after \section
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{section}

\begin{document}
    \rule{\textwidth}{15cm}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section*{Section 1}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```