# How to reduce the space before & after \section and \subsection

Tags: spacing, sectioning

How to reduce the space before and after titles specified by \section and \subsection

- \subsection

### [image: \subsubsection]

---

- \section

[image: \section]

Comment: You can find very similar questions in the "Related" bar, e.g. [Reducing spacing after headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53338) and [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390) Do the answers to those questions help you?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `\titleformat*` from the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.1\baselineskip}{0.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
asdkfjhsakdjfhsdaf
\section{Second}
asldfhsajldfh
\end{document}
```

with the first number (0.1) adjusting the space above and second number (0.2) adjusting the space below.

For more details, see section 3.2 in the manual: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf

Comment: This didn't help me (nothing changed).

Comment: Instead why didn't you use `0.9\baselineskip` to reduce space?