# Unwanted extra space after header of first section, using multicols article

Tags: spacing, multicol, article

I'm a beginner of LaTex, so I'm sorry if I've asked an easy question. I'm writing a scientific article, and after only the first header of the first section I get an unwanted extra space. Here is the output, with specified the space that I want to remove:

[image]

And here is the first part of code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}


% ------
% Fonts and typesetting settings
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % codifica di output, T1 per lingue occidentali
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % codifica di input (un'alternativa è latin11)
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel} % lingua del documento (l'ultima è la principale)
\linespread{1.05}               % Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{lipsum}         % generatore di lorem ipsum
\usepackage{emptypage}          % pagine vuote SENZA testatine
\usepackage{pdfpages}           % inserire pagine PDF
\usepackage{graphicx}           % inserire immagini
\usepackage{listings}           % aggiunta di codice sorgente indentato
\usepackage{quoting}            % citazioni
\quotingsetup{font=small}       % setup citazioni
\usepackage{color}              % colori
\usepackage{microtype}


% ------
% Page layout
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}


% ------
% Lettrines
\usepackage{lettrine}


% ------
% Abstract
\usepackage{abstract}
    \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}


% ------
% Titling (section/subsection)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}


% ------
% Header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[C]{Andrea Romagnoli $\bullet$ Laurea triennale in Informatica $\bullet$     2013}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}


% ------
% Clickable URLs (optional)
\usepackage{hyperref}


    % ------
% Definizione delle parti delle sezioni di codice
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
    frame=tb,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
backgroundcolor=\color[HTML]{D8D8D8},
showstringspaces=false,
columns=flexible,
basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   
stringstyle=\color{mauve},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true
tabsize=3
}


% ------
% Definizione di JavaScript
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
morekeywords={function},
    sensitive=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,%emph={3}
    showtabs=false,
    numbers=left,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}
}

% ------
% Definisce il layout delle liste 'itemize'
\usepackage{enumitem}           
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=18pt, itemsep=0pt,parsep=2pt,topsep=8pt}


% ------
% Maketitle metadata
\title{\vspace{-15mm}%
\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\textbf{Inserire il titolo della tesi!}
    }   
\author{%
\large
\textsc{Andrea Ro} % \thanks{Template by \href{http://www.howtotex.com}        {howtoTeX.com}} 
\\[2mm]
\normalsize Università di , laurea\\
\normalsize \href{mailto:andrea.r}{andrea.r}
\vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\includepdf{CoverTHESIS.pdf}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent  Bisogna spiegare in poche parole perché è importante il lavoro, mostrare un     sommario dei risultati principali ottenuti, di circa 400 parole. Nel sommario bisogna     rispondere alle seguenti domande: Cos'è stato fatto? Perché è stato fatto, e quali sono le domande delle quali si cerca una risposta? Come è stato fatto il lavoro (modalità)? Cosa si è imparato? Perché è interessante?
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Introduzione}
\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{Q}uesta tesi nasce dal mio coinvolgimento con il         progetto , presso l'Azienda , durante il quale ho svolto il tirocinio formativo
previsto dal piano di studi.\newline
Il principale compito assegnatomi è stato di ridisegnare l'interfaccia del portale     pubblico di accesso al sistema, in quanto era sempre più stringente la necessità di avere
oltre che un sistema funzionale anche una veste di presentazione accattivante, visto     l'immimente rilascio del sistema tramite un'estesa campagna pubblicitaria.\newline
Prima di iniziare il design di un'interfaccia gradevole, ho raccolto informazioni circa il     progetto tramite dei colloqui con dei dirigenti di alcuni dei membri coinvolti, in     particolare:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Provincia Autonoma di
    \item Azienda 
    \item Fondazione
    \item welfare
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: I think you should refer to the following [Link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53338/reducing-spacing-after-headings)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: hm .... when i compile your code all i get is single line space, and that's looks like it should be there. 

1st option is to use \vspace{-0.5cm} after declaring section.

what you are looking for is set global geometry for sections.

Comment: \vspace works but not as I need, because I can get only a little space or too much, there isn't a way between, and the whitespace will go in the next section, so the problem persists

Comment: it looks like the paragraphs justify itself their text to fill the page, but I don't want this behavior

Comment: are you looking for `\raggedcolumns` ?

Comment: The code here doesn't compile cleanly, and even if you get past the issues doesn't show the problem. As such, it's not clear what is being asked.