# Spacing after KOMA-Script \section in multicol environment

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

I'm writing a two column paper using the KOMA-Script `scrartcl` class and the `multicol` package. However, I start with a one column header, title and nomenclature section which take up most of my first page. In my MWE, this space is taken by the `\rule`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=1ex]{section}

\begin{document}

\rule{\textwidth}{15cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the paragraph is divided in a very unfortunate way, only the last line is pushed to the next page. At the same time, the white space after "Section 1" is very large, even though I have defined the value of `afterskip` to only 1ex, which according to KOMA-Script documentation is the "official" way to deal with white space after section titles. The actually applied space is clearly larger than 1ex.

If I reduce the value even further (say to <0.1ex), at some point the first line of the paragraph "jumps" up and I get the desired behavior. But this is dependent on the fonts used and does not work for my preferred fonts.

I assume it is all just LaTeX' algorithm adjusting the white spaces to its criteria, but in this case it seems to make no sense.

**UPDATE:**
I have updated my MWE to include my fonts (Bera sans for sans, Charter for text body) since the problem seems to be font dependent.
In this updated case, even setting `afterskip=1sp` and `\raggedcolumn` doesn't help. I also feel a little bad about just setting `afterskip` to the smallest possible number, since I don't want to effect all of my section titles. Is it really all just latex fumbling with the vertical spaces, or is there another parameter involved?

Answer (score 8):

The `parskip=half` option results in additional space after a section heading. So you have to use `afterskip=1sp` together with `parskip=half`.

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=half% inserts additional space after \section
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=1sp]{section}

\begin{document}

\rule{\textwidth}{15cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In addition the `\flushcolumns` command (used by the `multicolumns` environment) may also insert additional white space. Thats why there is still a distance when I remove the `parskip=half` option:

[image]

---

To avoid this you can use `\raggedcolumns`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  %parskip=half% inserts additional space after \section
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=1sp]{section}

\begin{document}

\noindent%< added
\rule{\textwidth}{15cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns% <- added
\section*{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update:** You can change the `afterskip` for sections only inside the `multicols` Environment. And maybe you can use there a parindent instead the parskip.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

%\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1ex]{section}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{%
  \raggedcolumns%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{section}%
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=false}%
}

\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{15cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\section*{Section 2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use `parskip=full` inside  `multicols`

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{%
  \raggedcolumns%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{section}%
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=full}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, with my fonts, it still doesn't work. I have updated my question

Comment: @Niclas I have updated my answer.