# How to change section spacing article class

Tags: fonts, sectioning, fontsize

I want all my section headings and body text to be spaced as per below rule. I use article class.

Space before: 0pt

Space after: 50–100% of text size

Line spread = 135% of text size

How can this be done?

**EDIT:** MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}%                          Define titles and spacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}%                          Font specification
\usepackage{sectsty}%                               Section font
\usepackage{xcolor}%                                For colored things
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%   Font Declaration
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setmainfont{Futura Book.ttf}[
BoldFont = Futura Book Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont = Futura Book Italic BT.ttf,
BoldItalicFont = Futura Book Bold Italic.ttf]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%   Section Color.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}
\subsectionfont{\color{gray}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{gray}}
\paragraphfont{\color{gray}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%   Titlesec Customizations 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}        

\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Sub-Section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I was wondering, why do you need MWE? But while creating this MWE I realized there is something not agreeable between `titlesec` and `sectsty`. If I comment out the `section color` instructions in preamble, `titlesec` comes into effect.

Thank you [Arne](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18866/arne) for suggesting MWE.

I need coloured section headings AND the tight spacing. Help?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53338/reducing-spacing-after-headings

Comment: Yes I have. Set all to `0pt`. But it hasn't reduced the spacing.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt your question with a MWE. So we can see what you have done/tried.

Comment: Done. btw, how do I tag people here? The `@` seems to have no effect.

Comment: a MWE is very handy for two reasons. 1) possible errors can be found. 2) if you want to help, it is easier to start of a "working" file. It saves a lot of time.

Comment: Any solutions for this one? I am at the end of my line now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my answer, to this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ipsum}
\linespread{1.35}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}%                                For colored things
\usepackage{fontspec}%                          Font specification



\titleformat{\section}%
{\normalfont\Large\color{blue}}% format applied to label+text
{\parbox{1.1cm}{\thesection}}% label
{5pt}
{}


\titleformat{\subsection}%
{\normalfont\Large\color{gray}}% format applied to label+text
{\parbox{1.1cm}{\thesubsection}}% label
{5pt}
{}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-5pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 20pt} %the -5pt is space before, experiment with the numbers
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\subsection{test}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Resulting in : 
[image]

Futura font is not working with me. Hope I fits your needs

Comment: Sorry for sounding so thick...I tried to set all the values to `0pt` in `\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 20pt}` without any difference in spacing. Is there something I am doing incorrectly? I tried the negative values as well, without any luck...

The only way I can have the spacing to conform to the above values is by commenting out the `section color` in MWE.

Comment: No probs. Did you tried  \titlespacing\section{0pt}{50pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 20pt} %the 12pt is space before, experiment with the numbers. I've justed tried it here: https://www.overleaf.com/4178760rmvfzv

Comment: Even `\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}` works like a charm IF I comment out `\usepackage{sectsty}`. But I lose the section colors.

Comment: in Overleaf, the futura font is giving me problems. (I'm not on "my" computer now, so I can't really test it on an offline system.)... I will try again in 4h ok?

Comment: I have placed a sample on overleaf here: https://www.overleaf.com/4178760rmvfzv#/12317408/

Comment: Accepted this as a solution. Readers be aware that `sectsty` really messes up `titlesec` specifications. True story.