# How do I reduce spacing between chapter title and first section?

Tags: report

How do I reduce the spacing between the chapter title (Background) and the section (Recurrent Neural Networks)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
```

Comment: You could use the `titlespacing` command from the `titlesec` package. (See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53341/134144)

Comment: i tried \titlespacing{\section}{10pt}{-\parskip}{\parskip} but it is not changing the right thing

Comment: which code should i use and which bracket should i edit

Comment: \titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

Comment: Please tell us *by how much* you want to reduce the (vertical) whitespace between the two lines. By 50%, 75%, 100%, or by some other amount? Please advise.

Comment: I have figured out that I am supposed to use this command \titlespacing\chapter{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}. I dont want to change the position of chapter. Only the section below it. But that code changes the position of chapter. How do I pass in default arguments ? example. \titlespacing\chapter{DEFAULT}{DEFAULT}{20pt}

Comment: @kong: For that you can use `\titlespacing\chapter{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}`, where `0pt` and `50pt` are the default `<left>` and `<before>` separations (used in [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that if you want to reduce the space between the (numbered) chapter header and the following section header, you also want to reduce the space between the lines that contain the chapter number and the chapter header.

Here's a solution that doesn't use any packages (other than `etoolbox`, which allows the "patching" of existing macros).

Note that this solution does *not* affect the amount of whitespace *above* the chapter header.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\makeatletter
% No extra space between chapter number and chapter header lines:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 20}{\vskip 0} {}{}
% Reduce extra space between chapter header and section header lines by 50%:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{} % for unnumbered chapters
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\chapter{Background}
\section{Recurrent Neural Networks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{2cm}{3cm}
\begin{document}


\chapter{Title of Chapter}
\section{Title of Section}

\end{document}
```

Just needed an extra line of code. In `\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{2cm}{3cm}` adjust 1 to adjust the left margin, adjust 2 to adjust the vertical space before the title, adjust 3 to adjust the separation between title and non-sectioning text.

Comment: It might be helpful if you stated the default values of the three arguments of `\titlespacing`.

Comment: I guess, the default values you are looking for, have to do with the document class you are using (report). What i know for sure, is that you really don't need them. In case you want to return to the default spacing you can just omit the titlespacing section.