# How I can make space 10 pt between chapter and text?

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, polish

I'm writing a paper in latex and I want the space between the chapter title and the text to be 10pt horizontal, and the space between the chapter title. and subsection 10pt. Someone know how I can do it ?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\begin{document}

\chapter{Technologie tworzenia aplikacji webowych}

\section{Technologie do modelowania aplikacji}

\subsection{Język UML}

Język UML (ang.\ Unified Modeling Language) jest to technologia 
służąca do modelowania. Modelowanie to proces, za pomocą którego 
projektujemy aplikację, przed stworzeniem aplikacji~\cite{uml}.
Architektami którzy stworzyli język UML są G.\,Booch, I.\,Jacobson i
J.\,Rumbaugh~\cite{uml2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you actually referring to *section*s rather than *chapter*s? ... you do mention you're "writing a *paper*".

Comment: I write a report.

Comment: Can you provide the community with a template you're working with? We call it a minimal working example (or MWE) of the code. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what your setup is like. Can you do that?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by *horizontal* space between the *chapter title* and *text*. There's typically a *vertical* separation between those two and other sectional units.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I add code in my code.

Comment: The code is missing the document class. Ideally, the code should be compilable without modifications.

Comment: You wrote, "I want ... the space between the chapter title and subsection [to be] 10pt." Since there's a `\section` directive *between* the `\chapter` and `\subsection` directives, it's not feasible to have just 10pt of vertical whitespace between the chapter and subsection header strings. After all, one has to provide enough space for section header string.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use the `titlesec` package which provides the command `\titlespacing`.

`\titlepacing {command} {space left} {before space} {after space} [right]`.

Spaces can be negative.

The starred version `\titlepacing*` removes the indentation from the paragraph that follows the title.

For a good explanation of the `plus` and the `minus`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53341/161015

> Spacing: how to read {12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
>
> 12pt is what we would like the spacing to be
>
> plus 4pt means that TeX can stretch it by at most 4pt
>
> minus 2pt means that TeX can shrink it by at most 2pt
>
> This is one example of the concept of, 'glue', in TeX

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
    \else
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi
\usepackage{titlesec} % format titles   

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % needed for spacing the chapter  
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} 

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt} % space  left
{-50pt} % before title
{10pt  minus 1pt} %after  title  10pt <<<<<<<<<<<<

\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt} % space  left
{10pt plus 0.5pt minus 1pt} % before title
{10pt minus 1pt} %after title  10pt <<<<<<<<<<<<

\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt} % space left
{10pt plus 0.5pt minus 1pt} % before  title
{10pt minus 1pt} %after  title  10pt <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\chapter{Technologie tworzenia aplikacji webowych}

Aplikacje mobilne wykorzystują rozwiązania wewnętrzne wdrażane w ramach procesów organizacji.
Aplikacje doskonale sprawdzają się w środowiskach pracy, które wymagają poruszania się
lub nie mają miejsca na komputer.

\section{Technologie do modelowania aplikacji}

Najpopularniejszym typem aplikacji są te, skierowane do indywidualnego odbiorcy. 
Wśród nich można wyróżnić kilka różnych podtypów aplikacji, 
które różnią się przeznaczeniem i celem biznesowym.

\subsection{Język UML}

Język UML (ang.\ Unified Modeling Language) jest to technologia 
służąca do modelowania. Modelowanie to proces, za pomocą którego 
projektujemy aplikację, przed stworzeniem aplikacji~\cite{uml}.
Architektami którzy stworzyli język UML są G.\,Booch, I.\,Jacobson i
J.\,Rumbaugh~\cite{uml2}.

\end{document}
```