# Setting the upper margin of chapter titles in scrbook

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, chapters, titlesec

In a `scrbook` document I need to set the chapter titles close to the upper page margin, without leading number and with a `\hrule` afterwards. Redefining `\chapterheadstartvskip` does the trick with the margin but won't do the hrule and omits the number. With `titlesec` I can set the \hrule and number, but can't get the title move to the upper. Do I miss something in the `titlesec` setting?

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}

% is ignored when titlesec is used
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4\topskip}} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{}

\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\hrule\vspace*{-24pt}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foobar}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: unfinished layout]

Comment: You can use `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\noindent\hrulefill\par\kern1cm}` -- so you don't need any `titlesec`

Comment: An addition for later readers: [About KOMA-Script and titlesec incompatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/about-koma-script-and-titlesec-incompatibility).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like **Marco Daniel** said in his comment: you don't need `titlesec`. By redefing `\chapterheadendvskip` you can get the rule and by redefining `\chapterformat` you can also get rid of the number.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-4\topskip}} 
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{%
  \vskip-.5\baselineskip
  \noindent
  {\color{gray}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}%
  \par}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foobar}
\blindtext

\chapter{Blah}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or alternative: `\addchap` ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes, of course :) I tend to forget about the `\add<sth>` commands...