# Format appendix chapter title with titlesec in a scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, appendices, titlesec

I'm writing a longer text and redefined the Design of a Chapter start page using `titlesec`. For example

```
\documentclass[cleardoublepage=empty,fontsize=11pt,a4paper,twoside,DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref,titlesec,scalefnt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\relax\huge\color{blue}}%
    {\Huge\raggedleft{\textcolor{blue!25}{\scalefont{4}\thechapter}}}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mainmatter}
        \chapter{Eins}
    \end{mainmatter}
    \begin{backmatter}
        \chapter{Ein Beispiel}
    \end{backmatter}
\end{document}
```

Which sets the chapter number in light blue and huge to the right (see Chapter 1). But if i change into the `backmatter` to add an appendix chapter (which should be apendix A), the whole `titlesec` (from the second block) definition is lost.
I would like to have `A` as the “appendix number” and set to the right, as the chapter number before (and of course “A An Example” to the toc).

How can i achieve, that the numbering is set to A (and shown) and that the titlesec-definition is not lost?

Comment: This should be useful (I hope you understand German): [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec).

Comment: Actually, i am german, so thanks for the links. I looked at some of the topics earlier, but i can't find a way to get the chapter number to the right with the koma script ”replacements“ for `\titleformat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\backmatter` (which, BTW is -- like `\frontmatter` -- a switch, not an environment) will turn off sectioning numbering, including the numbering of appendices. Use `\appendix` instead of `\backmatter`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref,titlesec,scalefnt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\relax\huge\color{blue}}%
    {\Huge\raggedleft{\textcolor{blue!25}{\scalefont{4}\thechapter}}}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Eins}

\appendix
\chapter{Ein Beispiel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yah, okay, that's easier than mine :)

Comment: Actually, the `frontmatter` environment works fine, page numbers are roman, the PDF TOC is correct and the `backmatter` environment also does, what you mentioned.

But i couldn't find any documentation of these environments, you're right.

I wasn't aware, that `backmatter` turns numbering off. I thought Appendicies belong to the backmatter and was used to see them Numbered in roman numerals. So this solution is easier than i thought.

Comment: And - actually - that also solved my second problem concerning the pagestyle, that was also changed in the backmatter and now just works fine (“A. An Example” as it should be).

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest not to use `titlesec` but to redefine `\chapterformat` and use `\setkomafont{chapter}`?

In order to get your requirements for the back matter we need `\backmatter` *not* to set `\@mainmatterfalse` but to reset the chapter counter instead.

Here is one way:

```
\documentclass[cleardoublepage=empty,fontsize=11pt,a4paper,twoside,DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref,scalefnt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\makeatletter
% the chapter format:
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{%
    \hbox to \linewidth{\hfill{\normalfont\Huge\color{blue!25}\scalefont{4}\thechapter}}%
  }
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\Huge\color{blue!25}}

% redefinition of \backmatter:
\renewcommand*\backmatter{%
  \if@openright\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \renewcommand*\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}%
  \@ifundefined{hypersetup}
    {}{\renewcommand*\theHchapter{\Alph{chapter}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Eins}
\lipsum

\backmatter
\chapter{Ein Beispiel}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to use `\setkomafont` but wasn't able to reproduce for example the `\raggedleft` - well you did :) . Though locksteps solution is easier and nicer.

Comment: You could combine his and mine. This way you'd need one package less...

Comment: On the other hand, the code with titlesec is shorter, well nicer at least for the chapter number (and i use for example titletoc anyways). But maybe i'll give it a try.

Comment: Well, "nicer" is a subjective attribute but if you need `titletoc` anyway you can quite as well use it, of course.

Comment: Of course, that's just subjective.