# Lowercase small caps in section/subsection/…

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, small-caps

I'm interested in setting the titles of section and more in lowercase small caps. And I don't know how to automatically achieve this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\scshape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \section{Hello}
    \section{hello}
    \subsection{helloHello}
\end{document}
```

But if I write everything in lowercase, then the `\tableofcontents` doesn't look good unless I use small caps there too. I know about `\MakeLowercase{}` but this needs an argument.

By the way, as I noted, I just want to show them in lowercase small caps in the document, not in the table of contents, ….

Any ideas?

PS: I don't know if this is necessary, but I'm using the `MinionPro` package.

**EDIT**: after some research, apart from what is answered here, in [classicthesis.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) you can look at other different (or semi-different) method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At his [homepage](http://komescript.de), Markus Kohm, the author of KOMA-script, has code for majuscle in section headings.

I have slightly adapted the code from [Versalien in \section und \subsection?](http://www.komascript.de/node/946))

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\renewcommand{\scdefault}{ssc} % MinionPro's spaced small caps as standard

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Section}{}
\let\Section\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{%
  \@ifstar {\star@section}{\@dblarg\nonstar@section}%
}
\newcommand*{\star@section}[1]{%
  \Section*{\MakeLowercase{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\nonstar@section}[2][]{%
  \Section[{#1}]{\MakeLowercase{#2}}%
}
\let\Subsection\subsection
\renewcommand*{\subsection}{%
  \@ifstar {\star@subsection}{\@dblarg\nonstar@subsection}%
}
\newcommand*{\star@subsection}[1]{%
  \Subsection*{\MakeLowercase{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\nonstar@subsection}[2][]{%
  \Subsection[{#1}]{\MakeLowercase{#2}}%
}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\scshape}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Heading level 1}
\subsection{Heading level 2}

\end{document}
```

This solution works with starred sections. And it is easy to add more formatting by using the normal:

```
\setkomafont{level}{command}
\addtokomafont{level}{command}
```

I will also suggest that you use the package [textcase](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcase) to make the case changes more fool proof:

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

Comment: I like this option much more than the others, because I don't need to use another package. At first sight, it works for me. I will do a bit more of trying and also wait to see if anyone points something about this. If not, I think this is the final answer (to me).

Comment: @Manuel: Well, sveinung links to the source of inspiration, but forgot to add, that the original solution is from Markus Kohm, the KOMA-Script developer, himself.

Comment: @Speravir Sorry, it was not my intention not to give Markus Kohm credit. I was in a hurry. I have corrected the reference.

Comment: No problem, Sveinung. I added the remark also in reaction of Manuel’s statement “… because I don’t need to use another package”.

Comment: Then I really like this answer. Ah, the name of the package is `\usepackage{MinionPro}` instead of `\usepackage{minionpro}` for the sake of correctness.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an option using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noindentfirst, es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\large\thesection}{0.7em}{\textls{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\scshape}{\small\thesubsection}{0.7em}  {\textls{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Una Secci\'on de Prueba}
\subsection{Una Subsecci\'on de Prueba}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\MakeTextLowercase` command from the [`textcase`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package was used since, unlike standard `\MakeUppercase`, it doesn't change the case of any math­e­mat­ics, or the ar­gu­ments of `\cite`, `\la­bel` and `\ref` com­mands within the ar­gu­ment.

However, care should be taken with this approach (See [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954)).

Answer (score 9):

A patch that seems to do what you want is as follows. It will apply to *all* sectional units, though.

The `hyperref` package must be loaded *after* the patches have been applied.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[rm=oldstyle]{cfr-lm} % for oldstyle figures
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% patch the relevant commands to enclose the section title as argument to a command
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{#8\@@par}{\lowsmallcaps{#8}\@@par}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@ssect}{#5\@@par}{\lowsmallcaps{#5}\@@par}{}{}
\makeatother

% \usepackage{hyperref} % Must go after the patches

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape} % use small caps for section titles
\setkomafont{sectionentry}{\normalfont} % use normal font in the TOC

% make everything lower case in section titles
\newcommand\lowsmallcaps[1]{\textls{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section With Mixed Case}

\subsection{This is small caps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A different way, inspired by Sveinung's answer, is to redefine the commands; be careful that some other package didn't redefine them, because this could cause conflicts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{textcase,color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\changesectionalcommand}{mm}
 {
  \cs_new_eq:cN { csc_\cs_to_str:N #1 } #1
  \RenewDocumentCommand{#1}{som}
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
     {
      \IfValueT{##2}{ \use:c { phantomsection } }
      \use:c { csc_\cs_to_str:N #1 } * { #2 { ##3 } }
      \IfValueT{##2}{ \addcontentsline{toc}{\cs_to_str:N #1}{##2} }
     }
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{##2}
       {
        \use:c { csc_\cs_to_str:N #1 } [ ##3 ] { #2 { ##3 } }
       }
       {
        \use:c { csc_\cs_to_str:N #1 } [ ##2 ] { #2 { ##3 } }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\changesectionnumber}{mm}
 {
  \cs_set:cpn { @seccntformat@\cs_to_str:N #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{@seccntformat@#1}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
}    

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\changesectionalcommand{\section}{\MakeTextUppercase}
\changesectionalcommand{\subsection}{\textcolor{red}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Mixed Case}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Red title}
\lipsum[2]

\section[Bar]{Foo}
\lipsum[2]

\section*{Foo foo}
\lipsum[2]

\section*[Bar bar]{Foo foo foo}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

A feature of this redefinition is that `\section*[<toc entry>]{Title}` is allowed, which will automatically perform the `\addcontentsline` instruction. Of course, one would usually type `\section*[Title]{Title}`.

The syntax is

```
\changesectionalcommand{\seccommand}{\macro}
```

where `\macro` receives an argument and `\seccommand` is one of the known sectional commands (from `\part` to `\subparagraph`).

For instance, to have sections in spaced lowercase small caps, one can say

```
\changesectionalcommand{\section}{\lowsmallcaps}
\newcommand{\lowsmallcaps}[1]{\normalfont\scshape\textls{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
```

(for `\textls`, `microtype` is needed).

However, also a corresponding change to the way the section number is typeset is needed, so a complement has been defined and the complete code would have also

```
\changesectionnumber{\section}{\normalfont}
```

or the section number would still be boldface, as usual.

[image]

Comment: Mmm, `hyperref` seems to make problems (sorry, but I didn't know that before), and this doesn't work.

Comment: @Manuel: Another incentive to create a minimal working example that duplicates your current setup. [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is important in this case, since hyperlinks are linked with sectional units, citations, table of contents and more...

Comment: @Werner I updated my original post. I don't really know what more can affect. But as I said, I didn't thought that this could alter the final result. Do you think I should list all my packages (just to make sure I don't miss something)?

Comment: @Manuel: You should just list packages that affect the sectional headers and the ToC (this was done by means of showing you use a KOMA-script class). [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is a good addition. If you're using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty), then include those as well. If not, don't worry. That's what comments to posts are also for; correction of updated material...

Comment: @Werner No, i'm not using those. May be `\usepackage[spanish, es-noindentfirst, es-nosectiondot]{babel}` affects. I will update the question.

Comment: @Manuel You have to load `hyperref` after doing the patch.

Comment: Well, this is a great answer. But I will mark the @Sveinung as accepted because it doesn't need any extra package. By the way, `\textls` is not necessary if you have the `microtype` loaded with `tracking=smallcaps` option, isn't it?

Comment: @Manuel I prefer to tell precisely when I want letterspacing, in particular for all caps text; for small caps one could agree that setting it once and for all may be good.

Comment: @Manuel If you use MinionPro, you may have spaced smallcaps by using the command `\renewcommand{\scdefault}{ssc}`.

Comment: @egreg KOMAscript has its own font changing command `\setkomafont{level}{command}` and `\addtokomafont{level}{command}`. For example: `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape}` changes all headings to the main font and small caps, including numbering.

Comment: @Sveinung I know, but other classes don't have that feature.

Comment: @egreg Just put in an `if`-test =:-)

Comment: @Sveinung Yes, I know. And that's what I'm actually using.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with KOMA-Script version 3.19 you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
 \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{\MakeLowercase{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
```

and use

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\scshape}
\setkomafont{sectionentry}{\normalcolor}
```

to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
 \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{\MakeLowercase{#4}}%
}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\scshape}
\setkomafont{sectionentry}{\normalcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the `sectsty` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
\section{Anyone Home?}
\subsection{Hello Hello}
\end{document}
```

Note that the defaults of the KOMA-Script document with regard to listing section-level headers (sans-serif font, bold) and subsection-level headers (serif font, non-bold) are preserved. If I understand your specifications, this is something that you want.

Comment: But this doesn't make the letters lowercase.

Comment: @Manuel - fixed by adding the `\lowercase` instruction to the argument of `\allsectionsfont`.

Comment: I don't know, but if I add the MinionPro package, the font of the headers stays Computer Modern… **EDIT:** the same if I load any font, utopia, charter, palatino, etc.

Comment: @Manuel -- I'm afraid I don't have access to the MinionPro package and therefore can't tell you what might be going on there. Are you loading the MinionPro package before or after the sectsty package?

Comment: Doesn't matter. `mathpazo` package, `mathdesign` package, `garamondx` package, also don't work.

Comment: @Manuel - Not sure what to say: The `mathdesign` package on my system (MacTeX2012) doesn't even feature a small-caps font, and loading either the `mathpazo` package (with the `sc` option set) or the mathptmx package definitely changes the small-caps font in use.

Comment: Mmm, not for me. `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` doesn't change the fonts of the small caps in the section names (of course, if I use `\textsc{…}` the command uses the palatino small caps).

Comment: As a minimal example, if I use ANY (`mathpazo`, `garamondx`, `fourier`, …) font package in the second line of your code, the small caps output doesn't change at all, except if the package changes de sectioning font to `\sffamily`. I don't know why it works for you, i.e., with `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`.