# Using commands inside environment definitions

Tags: environments

I want to do something like

```
\newenvironment{definition}
{
    \textit{
}
{
    }
}
```

but of course it doesn't work, the braces get mixed up. (In other words, I want that within my environment, the content is surrounded by a command such as \textit or \textbf for instance.) Any ideas?

EDIT : My environment now looks like this :

```
\newenvironment{definition}
{
    \textbf{\underline{Definition.}}
    \vspace{12 pt}
    \begin{itshape}
}
{
    \end{itshape}
}
```

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) please.

Comment: 12pt not 12 pt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your given example, you can define

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{\itshape}{}
```

Actually, the way environments work, you could just use

```
\begin{itshape} <content> \end{itshape}
```

but don’t, it is better to have environments named in a meaningful semantic way, say

```
\newenvironment{emphasize}{\itshape}{}
\begin{emphasize} <content> \end{emphasize}
```

---

If you really need to use a macro that expects a parameter (like `\textit`) you can use the [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) package and its `\BODY` macro as [demonstrated by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101588/16595).

Comment: Thanks! Actually I chose the \begin{itshape}/\end{itshape} first and it work just fine... what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva it is better to have a meaningful name for the environment. It's purpose surely isn't a demonstration of italic font shape, is it? IMHO the name of the environment should reflect its meaning and not what it is actually doing.

Comment: I edited my question to show what I actually did. Is it what you meant?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes, but remember, there isn’t an `itshape` environment but an `\itshape` font switch. A better definition would be `\newenvironment{definition}{\textbf{\underline{Definition.}}\vspace{12 pt}\itshape}}{}` (no additional group).

Answer (score 11):

In a general setting, you wish to capture the entire environment into a macro, and then pass that macro to another macro as an argument. That is exactly what the [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) package provides:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron{myenv}[1][\textit]{%
  #1{\BODY}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
Hello World!
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[\textbf]
Hello World!
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[\slshape]
Hello World!
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[]
Hello World!
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

`environ` allows you to capture the contents of the environment into the macro `\BODY`, which is then usable for whatever means. My definition prints it using `\textit` by default, but you can modify that using a different macro or font switch.

The above definition of `myenv` is general enough to allow for formatting of the environment content using a macro or a switch (as is done in the 3rd example). Supplying an empty (optional) argument removes any formatting.

Comment: Interesting package. I don't think I need something so refined to do a simple italic in an environment though, your package seems to be able to do a lot.

Comment: What if you want to use `\begin{verbatim}`? Then `\BODY` won't work...

Comment: @Someone True, but is it necessary in your instance? Do you have bizarre symbols you want within the output? There are some alternatives, but it may depend on your actual use-case.

Comment: I wanted to put verbatim text into a colored background.

Comment: @Someone: See [Getting verbatim with soft grey background, as in tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141100/5764)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myenv}{\fontshape{it}\selectfont}{\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
Before the environment

\begin{myenv}
Testing in the environment
\end{myenv}

Out of the environment
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you could just use `\itshape`. ;) As the environment itself acts as a group, you don’t need the end part.

Comment: Yeah, but I got yelled at in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99292/lowercase-small-caps-in-section-subsection/99295#99295 for getting clever with `\sc`, so I now try to stick to orthodox solutions... especially with Werner on the thread.

Comment: @Steven : I must admit I don't know much about \sc, and something clever is not really relevant to me because I'm asking for something but I want to be able to work with it a little bit, otherwise I don't understand what's going on and I can't adapt your ideas to my work. Codes that "read easily" are more appropriate answers than clever codes that are very intricate... I +1'ed your answer but I prefered Qrrbrbirlbel's.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : Understood, and thanks.  Here's a good reference for using/changing font attributes: http://latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes While `\sc` is a deprecated command, `\itshape` or `\scshape` aren't. Using lower level commands such as `\fontshape` and `\selectfont` is best avoided if higher level declarations are available.

Comment: @egreg Thanks.  I can't win, it would seem. I must have difficulty keeping it all straight, but I appreciate the reminders.