# Getting verbatim with soft grey background, as in tex.stackexchange

Tags: color, verbatim, backgrounds

Given a verbatim as on below,

```
\begin{verbatim}
This is an awesome verbatim
\end{verbatim}
```

which is displayed with no background on the compiled pdf page :

> This is an awesome verbatim

I would like to have a soft grey background on this verbatim instead. The result on the compiled pdf page would be :

> ```
> This is an awesome verbatim
> ```

Is there a simple way doing it, still using the verbatim (ie. not using listings)? Thank you in advance.

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION :**

Is this possible to do the same with `\texttt{not usual verbatim but still code quote}` and getting also a grey background for all `\texttt{*}` elements ?
It would also display :

> `not verbatim but still code quote`

Comment: Maybe `fancyvrb` could help you.

Comment: @Sigur I don't know this package actually.

Comment: @Martingal It's on CTAN http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb. You should also be able to look at the documentation by calling `texdoc fancyvrb` from the command line. Maybe the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package is also worth to be checked out

Comment: Duplicate of your initial question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62202/change-background-colour-of-verbatim-environment

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's not a duplicate. Check the content and the request, I also took a look at this post, however it didn't answered to my need.

Comment: Sorry, I commented without noticing your additional question, and edited my comment a few minutes later. (I cannot see how your original question is *not* a duplicate of the one I mentioned though, I read it as exactly the same question.)

Answer (score 20):

You can use `fancyvrb`; I present two solutions, one with the background only below the actual contents, the other one going all the way to the line width.

For the additional question you can use `newverbs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for this example

\definecolor{cverbbg}{gray}{0.93}

\newenvironment{cverbatim}
 {\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
  \colorbox{cverbbg}{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
  \endflushleft
}
\newenvironment{lcverbatim}
 {\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
  \colorbox{cverbbg}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
  }
  \endflushleft
}

\newcommand{\ctexttt}[1]{\colorbox{cverbbg}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}
  {\setbox\verbbox\hbox\bgroup}
  {\egroup\colorbox{cverbbg}{\box\verbbox}}

\begin{document}
Some verbatim mid line \cverb|$a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$| and other words. Also
a simple \ctexttt{typewriter text} with its background.

\lipsum[1]
\begin{cverbatim}
Something 
verbatim
\foo
\end{cverbatim}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{lcverbatim}
Something 
verbatim
\foo
\end{lcverbatim}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\cverb` command doesn't seem to work for me. Any idea why?

Comment: @user545424 Because the definition somehow slipped out of the code. Fixed.

Comment: How can we `\label` these customized verbatim environments for referencing? Thank you.

Comment: @codeaviator Unless you add a number somewhere…

Comment: @egreg Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @codeaviator If an object has no number (or some kind of label), referencing it is impossible. If you have some ideas, please ask a new followup question.

Comment: Where can I change the font size? I would like it small.

Comment: @SergioAraujo `\makeatletter\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\normalfont\small\ttfamily}` (if you don't need it at various sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, with the `verbatimbox` package.

The answer has been edited to allow the verbatim to optionally take up the full text width, by stuffing `\theverbbox` into a full width `\parbox`.  One downside to this `verbbox` approach is that `\theverbbox` cannot extend across page boundaries

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
Not verbatim
\begin{verbbox}[\scriptsize]
Inline \scriptsize \verbatim
\end{verbbox}
\colorbox{lightgray}{\theverbbox}
Not vermatim\par
Not verbatim
\begin{verbbox}[\itshape]
This is multi-line \itshape \verbatim
with variable width, &%^@
that can be presented on separate lines with the use of \par
\end{verbbox}
\par\colorbox{lightgray}{\theverbbox}\par
Not verbatim
\begin{verbbox}
This is \verbatim
made to look full width
with the use of \par's and a full width \parbox
\end{verbbox}
\par\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\theverbbox}}\par
Not verbatim
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted that last setup as its own envirnment, the define it as

```
\newenvironment{fullgrayverb}
{\verbbox}
{\endverbbox\par\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\theverbbox}}\par}
```

and employ it as follows

```
\begin{fullgrayverb}
\verbatim
full width
gray background
in its own \newenvironment
\end{fullgrayverb}
```

Comment: I see, but I would like to have this grey on all my verbatims and not `verbbox`. I mean, the `verbbox` display is not the same than `verbatim` (ie. ends of line).

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{framed,color,verbatim}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}

\newenvironment{code}%
   {\snugshade\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endsnugshade}

\begin{document}
text

\begin{code}
line one
line two
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Looks like this-

[image]