# How to change font size for verbatim as used with colorbox?

Tags: fontsize, verbatim

Answer in [Getting verbatim with soft grey background, as in tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141100/getting-verbatim-with-soft-grey-background-as-in-tex-stackexchange)

Shows how to make verbatim with gray background. But I am not able to make it show with smaller font size. comment below the answer says to do  (I am using `\tiny` instead of `\small` but either one do not work)

```
\makeatletter\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily}
```

but this had no effect. I must not be using it correctly?

So instead of cluttering the comments in the above answer, I am making a new question asking how to change the font size for the verbatim environment as shown in the above answer.

I know how to do it using normal `Verbatim` command. But not using the above code. Here is MWE where code is taking from the above answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}
\definecolor{cverbbg}{gray}{0.95}

\newenvironment{cverbatim} 
 {\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
  \colorbox{cverbbg}{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
  \endflushleft
}

\makeatletter\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

This is my verbatim. How to make font tiny? now font size does not change

\begin{cverbatim}
int main() { 
printf("hello, world");

`Methods for first order ODEs:

return 0;
}
\end{cverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Which when compiled using `lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image]

Everything is good, except the font size has not changed. I know I can explicitly add `\tiny` before and then add `\normalsize` after to make it work, but I do not want to keep doing this. I want the verbatim to automatically typeset in `\tiny` font.

How to correctly implement the above so that verbatim font size comes out in the smaller font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\newenvironment{cverbatim}
{\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
{\endSaveVerbatim
\tiny\flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \colorbox{cverbbg}{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
    \endflushleft
}
```

[image: c]

(remove `\makeatletter\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily}` from you code)