# How to force lower case in small caps section titles?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, small-caps

I want my section titles to appear in lower case small caps. I tried to define a way to force lower case, but it doesn't work.

```
\\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\\usepackage{textcase}
\\newcommand\\textlcsc[1]{\\scshape{\\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\\usepackage{titlesec}
\\titleformat*{\\section}{\\normalfont\\fontsize{40}{50}\\bfseries\\sffamily\\color{pinterestred}}
\\titleformat*{\\subsection}{\\normalfont\\Large \\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{electricblue}}
\\titleformat*{\\subsubsection}{\\normalfont\\large\\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{pinterestred}}
\\titleformat*{\\paragraph}{\\normalfont\\normalsize\\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{electricblue}}
\\titleformat*{\\subparagraph}{\\normalfont\\normalsize\\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{electricblue}}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are all your `\\ ` typos or do you really have that in your code? Have you tried to use `\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}`?

Comment: I use Emacs org-mode, that's the syntax. Thanks, I tried adding \\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}, but it had no effect on the case.

Comment: Is it normal that the command you created is not used with the section but only with the other titles? Have a look at this [question and answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99292/31058), does it help?

Comment: That worked thanks! \\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
\\titleformat*{\\section}{\\normalfont\\fontsize{40}{50}\\bfseries\\sffamily\\color{pinterestred}}
\\titleformat*{\\subsection}{\\normalfont\\Large \\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{electricblue}\\MakeTextLowercase}
\\titleformat*{\\subsubsection}{\\normalfont\\large\\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{pinterestred}\\MakeTextLowercase}
\\titleformat*{\\paragraph}{\\normalfont\\normalsize\\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{electricblue}\\MakeTextLowercase}
\\titleformat*{\\subparagraph}{\\normalfont\\normalsize\\textlcsc\\rmfamily\\color{electricblue}\\MakeTextLowercase}

Comment: This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99292/lowercase-small-caps-in-section-subsection . Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.