# layout section heading

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Language requires the following layout for section headings:

b. The number and the following period should be in boldface; the heading text should be in SMALL CAPITALS.

d. Do not use more than two levels of headings: for example, 1 or 2.3 are fine, but not 3.2.4. If a further division of the section is necessary, simply use SMALL CAPS for the subsection heading, with no number.
METHODS. Experiment 1 took place in a sound-attentuated lab ...
e. Place section headings on a line with the section number and the first line of the section.
1. INTRODUCTION. The recent renaissance of ...

Is there a way to do this without touching the original text? Currently I have:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % Silbentrennung

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\scshape}
\let\subsubsection=\paragraph

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

In this section I want to show that \ldots


\subsection{Subsection 1}

The special focus here is on \ldots

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}

This subsubsection is allegal and should come out as a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

What is missing is the boldface of the number and a dot after the number and a dot after the section title and some setting that treats section and subsection titles like paragraphs. Is there a way to do this in Koma Script?

Comment: If you are required to use small caps, I would consider using *TeX Gyre Termes* – a Times look-alike – which gives you something inbetween petite caps and (true!) small caps. Replace `\usepackage{times}` with `\usepackage{tgtermes}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`komascript`'s tools for formatting headings are great, but won't be enough if you want the numbers and titles formatted separately. Here's how to go about it. This uses [titlesec](/questions/tagged/titlesec). (by the way, what's the language that requires you to do all this? I find it offensive, really)

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % Silbentrennung
\usepackage{times}      
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\let\subsubsection\paragraph

\newcommand{\periodafter}[1]{#1.}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\scshape}{\textbf{\thesection.}}{1ex}{\periodafter}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\scshape}{\textbf{\thesubsection.}}{1ex}{\periodafter}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\scshape}{}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

In this section I want to show that \ldots


\subsection{Subsection 1}

The special focus here is on \ldots

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}

This subsubsection is allegal and should come out as a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

PS: I do like those vintage periods finishing off the titles, though.

[image]

Comment: Language is the journal of the Lingusitics Society of America. Thanks a lot. I added \periodafter to paragraph and [run] in to the others and this did the trick. I think the rationale behind this layout is to safe as much space as possible. Hardly readable ...

Answer (score 3):

There are some incompatibilities between `titlesec` and the classes from the KOMA-Script bundle; see [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954) .A solution, not involving `titlesec`, is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{0em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{0em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{0em}{}{}
\renewcommand\sectfont{\normalfont\scshape}
\def\@seccntformat#1{{\bfseries\csname the#1\endcsname.}\quad}
\apptocmd{\@sect}{.~}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@ssect}{.~}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
In this section I want to show that \ldots

\subsection{Test Subsection}
The special focus here is on \ldots

\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
This subsubsection is legal; it comes out as a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]