# Customizing Chapter style in scrbook

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, formatting, koma-script, titlesec

I want to obtain styles like those showed in the next two images (I do not need the picture in the background (parabolas)):
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

My original LaTeX code (to be customized but should keep font as they are):

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=auto, version=last, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
%% En 12pt c'est possible aussi
%% packages utilises
%%---------------------
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % pour taper les lettres accentues
%====Perso====%
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
%=================%
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\pretocmd{\ref}{\bgroup\small}{}{}
%\apptocmd{\ref}{\egroup}{}{}
%=============%
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes} % csquotes va utiliser la langue définie dans babel
%%========Headings(perso)======================%
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%Chapter%%%%%%%
\setkomafont{chapter}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
%%%%%Section%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont} % "qhv" - TeX Gyre Heros, "b" - bold
    {} 
    {0em}
   {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

In the follwing solution just replace the green rule - e.g. `\color{green} \rule{0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}` - with `\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{yourpicname}` while using the `graphics` or `graphicx` package. And you should apply the color theme you like. I just used plain old 'blue' for the demonstration.

### The Code

```
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=auto, version=last, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
\usepackage{xcolor,anyfontsize,realboxes}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \hspace*{-1in} %customize this to your needs
  \makebox[0.42\textwidth][c]{%
    \raisebox{-.5em}[0.4\textwidth][0cm]{%
      \color{green} \rule{0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
          \put(-52,24){%
            \Colorbox{blue}{%
            \parbox{0.11\textwidth}{%
            \centering
            \small\color{white}
            \chaptertitlename\par
            {\fontsize{38}{41}\selectfont\thechapter\par}
            \vspace{.5em}
            }}
         }   
    }
  }
}
\newcommand{\sectionformat}{%
  \raisebox{-.65em}[0cm][0cm]{%
    \Colorbox{blue}{%
    \parbox{3em}{%
      \centering
      \color{white}
      \thesection
    }}
  }
}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\huge\bfseries\color{blue}}{\chapterformat}{0em}{}
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
    \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\Large\color{blue}} % "qhv" - TeX Gyre Heros, "b" - bold
    {\sectionformat} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{.75em}}
    [\vspace*{-.75em}\rule{2.25em}{0pt}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

(Note that I don't changed the fonts as you requested, although the fonts in your example pic are slightly different. There are some small caps and italics.)

Comment: Thank you. But the result is quite different. The font applied to the chapter name and number still not the same. Also, the position of the line need to be much lower and fit the page's margins and the name of the section have to approach more the line (like what we see if we use an underline command). Finally, is there any way to move up the position of the block {chapter name, number} a little higher? Tank you again.

Comment: I finally found how to change the chapter font. There no need to the command "\setkomafont{chapter}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}". It suffice to use "\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge" into the \titleformat{\chapter}.

Comment: @SAKLY Note, that `titlesec` is according to Markus Kohm, the KOMA-Script developer, not fully compatible to KOMA-Script classes (and `scrextend`). If you understand German, see my answer in [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec). Perhaps you stumbled here over such an incompatibility. Maybe it would have worked, if the `\setkomafont{chapter}` line would have been set _after_ all `titlesec definitions`. Your solution is the “raw” LaTeX version.

Answer (score 6):

Please note, you should not use `titlesec` with KOMA-Script classes. Instead you should use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and`\setkomafont` and redefine `\chapterlinesformat` (or `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`) and `\sectionlinesformat`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,% not needed, because it is the default
  pagesize=auto,% not needed, because it is the default
  version=last,% as long as you don't use deprecated options not needed
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}% frenchb is deprecated
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{tgheros}% You could also use \usepackage{helvet}.
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize}

\newkomafont{chapterformat}{\fontsize{64}{64}\normalfont\bfseries\color{number}}
\newkomafont{chapterformattext}{\normalfont\small\itshape}
\newkomafont{sectionformat}{\Large\color{number}}
\colorlet{numberbackground}{blue}
\colorlet{disposition}{DeepSkyBlue}
\colorlet{number}{white}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{disposition}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape}
\newcommand*{\chapterimage}{example-image}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  {%
    \usekomafont{chapterformat}{%
      \raisebox{-\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax}{%
        \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth,height=.3\textwidth]{\chapterimage}%
      }%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \colorbox{numberbackground}{%
          \parbox[b]{1em}{\centering
            {\usekomafont{chapterformattext}{\chapapp\\[-1ex]}}%
            \thechapter% \autodot?
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \enskip
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    #2\parbox[b]{.65\textwidth}{\raggedchapter #3}%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \colorbox{numberbackground}{%
    \makebox[5em]{\usekomafont{sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot}}%
  }%
  \hskip 1em\nobreak
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \hskip#2#3\nobreak
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-6em-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-#2\relax}{%
      {\raggedsection#4\par}%
      \vskip -\ht\strutbox
      \hskip -1em\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+1em}{1pt}%
    }%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\RedeclareSectionCommand[indent=.1\textwidth]{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\section{Test section}

\chapter{What happens if the chapter title is too long}
\section{What happens if the section title also needs more than one
line}

\end{document}
```

[image: One line chapter and section]

This also works for chapter or section titles with more than one line:

[image: Two line chapter and section]

For not numbered chapters it prints a title without background image:

[image: Table of contents]

If you want the background image in this case too, you have to move the output of the background image from `\chapterformat` to `\chapterlinesformat`.

If you want to change the color of the chapter entries to the table of contents, you can change the font of element `chapterentry`, e.g.:

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalcolor}
```

Comment: A old work done very well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  pagesize=auto,
  version=last,
  chapterprefix=true
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\newcommand\ChapterFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\huge\color{myblueii}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\parbox[b]{70pt}{\mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{50pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt][t]{45pt}{\centering%
        \color{white}%
        {\itshape\rmfamily\small\chaptertitlename}%
        \vfill{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\thechapter}%
        }%
      }%
    }\hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright\scshape#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\huge\color{myblueii}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\parbox[b]{70pt}{\mbox{}}%
    \hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright\scshape#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\small\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
  {\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox[c][16pt][c]{40pt}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}{\SectionFont\Large\rmfamily\thesection}%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {1em}
  {#1}
  [\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}%
    \color{myblueii}\hspace*{\dimexpr40pt+2\fboxsep\relax}%
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-40pt-2\fboxsep\relax}{1pt}%
  ]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `titlesec` is used, a warning will be issued by the KOMA classes.