# How to make this chapter heading style?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

As `fncychap` has no such chapter style, and using the `memoir` class will cause a lot conflicts with my current settings (`book` class), how to make this style (perhaps using the `titlesec` package)?

1. title style for `table of contetns`, `Nomenclature`, `References`, etc
2. title style for `chapters`

[image]

Comment: It could help if you told us what chapter style you'd use in `memoir` to generate this.

Comment: It's similar to the styles at page 48 and 50: ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/documentation/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf

Comment: Some guidelines can be taken from: [Customizing Chapter style in `scrbook`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150923/5764); [Customizing chapter style with `tikz`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160320/5764). As it stands, this is very much a do-it-for-me question...

Comment: I suppose the table of contents here  is the chapter table of contents?

Comment: The table of contents is the global one.

Comment: With some difficulty and only by devoting free time.  Have you not even started to try to work on it?  Give people a break, and at least provide a basic document to work with...  Also: the way it looks now, it almost looks like your 'chapter style' will be: 2 horizontal lines; the phrase 'Table of Contents'; verticle space; fancy 'chapter <num>'; two horizontal lines; <chapter title>.  But really, you just want a numbered style and an unnumbered style, right?

Comment: well, I mainly focus on my thesis itself. If I could do this, maybe it will take several days! But for experienced people, perhaps few minutes. This is why I post my question here.

Comment: @KOF The document you linked no longer exists!

Comment: well, you can search "MemoirChapStyles.pdf"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One option using TikZ (a TikZ-free solution is provided below); adjust the font attributes and lengths according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue}}
  {\filleft%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      outer sep=0pt,
      text width=2.5cm,
      minimum height=3cm,
      fill=myblue,
      font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
      align=center
      ] (num) {\thechapter};
    \node[
      rotate=90,
      anchor=south,
      font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
      ] at ([xshift=-5pt]num.west) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  {10pt}
  {\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Betratronic motion in a synchrotron}

\end{document}
```

An unnumbered chapter:

[image]

A numbered chapter:

[image]

A TikZ-free option:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue}}
  {\filleft\hspace*{-60pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \normalfont\color{black}\Large%
        \textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}%
    }\hspace{10pt}%
    {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \colorbox{myblue}{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{2.5cm}{%
      \centering\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }}%
  }
  {10pt}
  {\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Betratronic motion in a synchrotron}

\end{document}
```

An unnumbered chapter:

[image]

A numbered chapter:

[image]

### Some remarks:

- The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used to easily change the formatting for chapter headings.
- The [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package was used to use \textls to space out the letters in "Chapter".
- The [`lmodern`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) package was used just to have access to a 80pt font size.
- I used [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) in the first solution to quickly place some of the elements; the second option is a TikZ-free solution.

Comment: @KOF You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use `TikZ`?

Comment: @Holene my first answer was the one using TikZ :) (and I am an admirer of TikZ); I included a TikZ-free possibility since I think this is one of the cases in which using TikZ for such a simple task might be an overkill; TikZ is such a heavy package and consuming resources for simple tasks is not really needed.