# Memoir chapter in book class

Tags: memoir, books

I want to use the following chapter style in my book:

```
\usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}  
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}  
\makeatletter  
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw  
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}  
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}  
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}  
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%  
\sbox\feline@chapter{%  
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%  
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%  
}}%  
\rotatebox{90}{%  
\resizebox{%  
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%  
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%  
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%  
}  
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%  
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%  
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap  
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%  
}}  
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{  
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}  
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}  
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}  
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}  
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}  
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}  
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}  
}  
\makeatother  
\chapterstyle{daleif1}
```

Which should look like this:
[image]

However, this chapter style is meant to be used in the memoir class and I already wrote more than half a book in the book class, so it would be hard for me to chenge class. There is some way to use this chapter style in the book class?

Thanks!

Comment: Memoir is based on `book` document class, so the change from `book` to `memoir` is not so demanding. You can capabilities of `memoir` consider latter or simple not use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (  [How to make this chapter heading style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/how-to-make-this-chapter-heading-style))     may help .... You may costumize it according to your needs .