# writing course note

Tags: beamer

[image]

[image]

I want to write this text like this using tex and modify on it, if you have the adequate preamble thanks

Comment: Note that this site is not a just-do-it-for-me-for-free service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146529/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: You could try `\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}
 your notes
\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}` as a starting point

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to get some chapters of the sort you seem to aim at. It is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169435/121799).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{lbl}{RGB}{62,108,136}
\definecolor{mbl}{RGB}{120, 178, 210}
\definecolor{bbl}{RGB}{222, 233, 240}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169435/121799
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue}}
  {%\filleft%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[white,fill=bbl]
    (0,0) -- (7,-2) -- (8,-2) --cycle;
    \draw[white,fill=black]
    (0,0) -- (6,-2) -- (7,-2) --cycle;
    \draw[bbl,thick,left color=lbl,right color=lbl,middle color=mbl]
    (0,0) |- (6,-2) --cycle;
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm]
    \draw[white,fill=bbl]
    (0,0) -- (7,-2) -- (8,-2) --cycle;
    \draw[white,fill=black]
    (0,0) -- (6,-2) -- (7,-2) --cycle;
    \draw[bbl,thick,left color=lbl,right color=lbl,middle color=mbl]
    (0,0) |- (6,-2) --cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \node[anchor=south,
      outer sep=0pt,
      font=\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont,
      align=center,text=myblue
      ] at (\textwidth/2,-5cm) {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter};
     \node[anchor=north, font=\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont,
      align=center,font=\Huge,text=brown] at (\textwidth/2,-5.2cm)
      {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  {10pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Systems of linear equations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create a slide you can use the beamer package that can be used to create slides and posters, below example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{Hello World}
\author{Davi}
\institute{StaxExchange}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```