# Change chapter style and color

Tags: chapters

I'm Working on a thesis (book class) and I want to change chapters' style to look like in the figure below: I want to delete "chapter" word and make chapter counters in a single box[image]

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) This is a Q&A site, not a "please do this for me service", so at least show us what you have so far. Your choice of class and packages greatly affects answers to a question like this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are are many similar questions on the site. Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings

Comment: Customising sections layout at any level is usually done through the `titlesec`package.

Comment: some similar style: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/how-to-make-this-chapter-heading-style

Comment: Universities usually have style requirements for theses.  Are you sure this will be accepted?