# Customizing chapter and section style (scrbook)

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script, titlesec

I have found a very cool custom style for chapter and section headings (It is from [Customizing Chapter style in scrbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150923/customizing-chapter-style-in-scrbook)):

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  pagesize=auto,
  version=last,
  chapterprefix=true
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\newcommand\ChapterFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\huge\color{myblueii}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\parbox[b]{70pt}{\mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{50pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt][t]{45pt}{\centering%
        \color{white}%
        {\itshape\rmfamily\small\chaptertitlename}%
        \vfill{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\thechapter}%
        }%
      }%
    }\hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright\scshape#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\huge\color{myblueii}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\parbox[b]{70pt}{\mbox{}}%
    \hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright\scshape#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\small\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
  {\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox[c][16pt][c]{40pt}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}{\SectionFont\Large\rmfamily\thesection}%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {1em}
  {#1}
  [\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}%
    \color{myblueii}\hspace*{\dimexpr40pt+2\fboxsep\relax}%
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-40pt-2\fboxsep\relax}{1pt}%
  ]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

I have two problems with it.

First, I want the chapter heading a bit bigger and the name of the section heading should also be bigger. How can this be done?

Second, I want the chapter heading to be not indented, i.e it should be left centered.

Edit: I have now tried out the approach by esdd for not breaking the KOMA-class and I have now several problems:

1. In the list of contents the chapter titles are in blue but the section titles are in black. Is it possible to have also the chapter titles in black?
2. Is it possible to make the line a bit lower as in the example of Benjaming? For me this lower line looks better. Please see the image below.
3. Benjamin also made subsubsection title without a numbering (because otherwise it is too much styling). Please also see the image below. Is this also possible?

[image]

Edit 2: Now everything is almost perfect except the line below the title. In your example it looks great but if I use it in my document the line appears lower. I tried different things but I can't find the solution. Do you see where the problem is? I also don't know if my template is perfect or if there are other mistakes. Please see below the example.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,chapterprefix=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[footnotesize,sl,SL,hang,tight]{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[font={small,sl},hang,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ifpdfoutput{%
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage[]{pdfpages}
}{%
    \usepackage{graphicx}
}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headinclude}

% **** Defining chapter style start ****

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblueii}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\itshape\rmfamily\small\color{white}}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalcolor}% entrys in tableofcontents not blue

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection and lower unnumbered

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt]{45pt}{\centering%
        {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chaptername}}%
        \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
        \vspace{6pt}%
      }}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox{40pt}{\centering\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}}}%
    \quad%
  }

\renewcommand\subsectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox{60pt}{\centering\usekomafont{subsectionnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot}}}%
\quad%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \par\nobreak%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{50pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-50pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \par\nobreak%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{70pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-70pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

% **** Defining chapter style end ****

% Define an own layer page style for the title page
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  addvoffset=\headsep,
  height=1.5cm,
  addheight=\dp\strutbox,
  contents={%
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{figures/ETH_logo.pdf}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{figures/CGL_logo.pdf}%
  }
  ]{titlepage.head}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepage.head}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ifpdfoutput{%
    \usepackage[pdftex,
        bookmarks,
        bookmarksopen=true,
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        pdfauthor={Rafael Wampfler},
        pdftitle={Engagement Detector: Modelling engagement dynamics in virtual environments},
        pdfsubject={The report of the master thesis about the modelling engagement dynamics in virtual environments.},
        pdfkeywords={machine learning, engagement dynamics, classification, virtual environments, calcularis, learning, minecraft},
        colorlinks=false,
        linkcolor=black,
        citecolor=black,
        filecolor=black,
        urlcolor=black,
        anchorcolor=black,
        menucolor=black,
        breaklinks=true,
        pageanchor=true,
        plainpages=false,
        linkbordercolor=red,
        citebordercolor=red,
        urlbordercolor=red,
        pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}
}{}

\ifpdfoutput{%
    \pdfcompresslevel=9
    \pdfoutput=1
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
}{}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\topmargin -0.5in
\textheight 9.3in
\textwidth 6.3in
\oddsidemargin 0.18in
\evensidemargin -0.22in
\parskip 0.1in
\parindent 0in

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\begin{document}

%% Define leading chapter pages
%
\input{studchapter}
\newpagestyle{mychapterpagestyle}{{\protect\mychpstyleintl}{\protect\mychpstyleintl}}{}
\newpagestyle{myappendixpagestyle}{{\protect\mychpstyleintl}{\protect\mychpstyleintl}}{}
%%

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%\include{abstract}

%\include{acknowledgment}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{mychapterpagestyle}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{} % show chapter titles only (no numbers)

% ---- MAIN PART ----

  \chapter{Chapter Title}
  \section{Section Title}
  \blindtext
  \addsec{Unnumbered Section Title}
  \blindtext
  \subsection{Subsection Title}
  \blindtext
  \subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
  \blindtext
  \blinddocument

% ---- END MAIN PART ----

\appendix
\clearpage
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{myappendixpagestyle}

%\include{appendix}

\clearpage
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

studchapter.tex

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{215pt}}

\def\mychpstyleintl{%
{\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\\[100pt]
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.6\linewidth}}
\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}}
\rightline{{%
\sffamily%
\fontseries{bx}%
\fontshape{n}%
\fontsize{100}{120}%choose baselineskip to be 1.2 times font size
\selectfont
\thechapter}}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}\\[300pt]
\end{tabular}
}}
```

[image]

Comment: This really breaks the KOMA interface so you end up with competing things trying to format the same document elements. I always think that's asking for trouble and confusion....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example without package `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblueii}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\itshape\rmfamily\small\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox[b][60pt]{45pt}{\centering%
      {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chapapp}}%
      \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
      \vspace{6pt}%
}}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \raisebox{-4pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \enskip\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}\enskip}%
  \quad%
}}

\renewcommand\subsectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \raisebox{-4pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \enskip\usekomafont{subsectionnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot}\enskip}%
  \quad%
}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-5pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}}%
  \@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{Section Title}
\blindtext
\addsec{Unnumbered Section Title}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update** because of updates in the question:

To get black chapter entries in the table of contents use

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalcolor}% entrys in tableofcontents not blue
```

If all subsections should be unnumbered use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection and lower unnumbered
```

And here is an example with lower rules:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblueii}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\itshape\rmfamily\small\color{white}}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalcolor}% entrys in tableofcontents not blue

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection and lower unnumbered

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt]{45pt}{\centering%
        {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chapapp}}%
        \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
        \vspace{6pt}%
      }}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox{40pt}{\centering\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}}}%
    \quad%
  }
  
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox{60pt}{\centering\usekomafont{subsectionnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot}}}%
\quad%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \par\nobreak%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{50pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-50pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \par\nobreak%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{70pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-70pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother
    
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Chapter Title}
  \section{Section Title}
  \blindtext
  \addsec{Unnumbered Section Title}
  \blindtext
  \subsection{Subsection Title}
  \blindtext
  \subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
  \blindtext
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**Update 2** because of a second update in the question

You are using a `\parskip` so `\par` inserts vertically space that must be removed:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parskip\z@% <- added, deactivates the parskip locally
    \par\nobreak
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{50pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-50pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \parskip\z@% <- added, deactivates the parskip locally
    \par\nobreak
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{70pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-70pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother
```

---

Some additional remarks:

Do not set `\parskip` manually! Use the KOMA-Script option `parskip=half-` instead. There are other values for this option like `half`, `half+`, `half*` and the same with `full`. For further explanations see the [scrguien.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (KOMA-Script documentation).

I would suggest to use package [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set the page margins.

To get an entry for the lists and the bibliography in the table of contents use the KOMA-Script options `listof=totoc` and `bibilography=totoc` instead of `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}`.

You redefine `\chapterformat` twice. Decide which one you want to use and remove the other.

The header of your new defined `mychapterpagestyle` is outside the paper.

Comment: Very nice, one of the better layouts, great!

Comment: Thank you for the example. What is the difference when not using titlesec? It looks very similar to the solution of Benjamin.

Comment: It is not recommended to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. You will get warnings regarding this from both the KOMA-Script class and `titlesec`. Note that Markus has some effort to ensure that KOMA-Script documents using `titlesec` will not break.

Comment: @esdd I have tried out your approach and have some questions. Please see my edited original post. Thank you very much.

Comment: @machinery See my updated answer.

Comment: @esdd Thank you again. There is one last point, see my Edit 2 in the original post. After that everything should be more than perfect.

Comment: @machinery I have updated my answer again.

Comment: @esdd Thank you so much. Now, everthing is perfect. I just have two questions regarding your recommendations for improving the code (parskip and geometry package). I have opened a new question for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289207/using-parskip-and-geometry-package-correctly-in-my-document

Comment: I really like this style for chapters etc. What I would like to understand is where the font is chosen and how it is? At the moment: When I use the code, I get a font for the chapter without serifs but the text of the chapter is the normal latex font with serifs. At least it is a very look a like font to the lmodern. What do I need to do to get the same font for the chapter's text as it is used in the chapter's title?

Comment: @Mike1993 The fonts were not my decision. The OP loads package `charter` - so charter is used as serif font. `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblueii}}` sets the font style for all headings (chapters, sections etc.) to `qhv` (TeXGyreHeros). The `\addtokomafont`, `\setkomafont` and `\newkomafont` change this settings for special headings or parts of the headings. If there is a `\rmfamily` in the argument, it switchs to the serif font (charter).

Comment: @esdd thanks for the explanation. I didn't see the charter package. Since I do use lmodern package only, I get the normal lmodern as serifs for everything with the '\rmfamily' command. The code above is now more clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Does this meet your conditions?

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  pagesize=auto,
  version=last,
  chapterprefix=true
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\newcommand\ChapterFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\newlength{\chapterfontsize}
\setlength{\chapterfontsize}{30pt}
\newlength{\sectionfontsize}
\setlength{\sectionfontsize}{14pt}
\newlength{\subsectionfontsize}
\setlength{\subsectionfontsize}{12pt}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\fontsize{\chapterfontsize}{\chapterfontsize}\color{myblueii}}%
  {}
  {0pt}
  {% <-- REMOVED INDENTATION
    \parbox[b]{50pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt][t]{45pt}{\centering%
        \color{white}%
        {\itshape\rmfamily\small\chaptertitlename}%
        \vfill{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\thechapter}%
        \vspace{6pt}%
        }%
      }%
    }\hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright\scshape#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\fontsize{\chapterfontsize}{\chapterfontsize}\color{myblueii}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {{\mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright\scshape#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{\sectionfontsize}{\sectionfontsize}\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}} %
  {\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox[c][1.2\sectionfontsize][c]{2\sectionfontsize}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}{\SectionFont\fontsize{1.2\sectionfontsize}{1.2\sectionfontsize}\rmfamily\thesection}%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {1em}
  {#1}
  [\vspace{-1\baselineskip}%
    \color{myblueii}\hspace*{\dimexpr2\sectionfontsize+2\fboxsep\relax}%
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\sectionfontsize-2\fboxsep\relax}{1pt}%
  ]

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{\sectionfontsize}{\sectionfontsize}\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {{\mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-150pt}{%
      \raggedright#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
  }
  [\vspace{-1\baselineskip}\color{myblueii}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}]

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{\subsectionfontsize}{\subsectionfontsize}\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}} %
  {\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox[c][1.2\subsectionfontsize][c]{3\subsectionfontsize}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}{\SectionFont\fontsize{1.2\subsectionfontsize}{1.2\subsectionfontsize}\rmfamily\thesubsection}%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {1em}
  {#1}
  [\vspace{-1\baselineskip}%
    \color{myblueii}\hspace*{\dimexpr3\subsectionfontsize+2\fboxsep\relax}%
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-3\subsectionfontsize-2\fboxsep\relax}{1pt}%
  ]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{\subsectionfontsize}{1.2\subsectionfontsize}\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
    {}
    {1em}
    {#1}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked very well. I have only a couple of things. 1. The chapter heading is still a bit too small (especially the box) 2. The box of the section heading (with the section number in it) is now a bit too small compared to the section title. 3. The abstract, acknowledgments, content, list of figures and list of tables headers are indented but I would prefer to have them not indented.

Comment: Ok, so I added two lengths where you can set the font size easily by yourself. The section boxes should scale quite well with the change of fantasize. What do you mean with your third remark. Can you update your MWE?

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks great. What do you mean with MWE? With the third remark I mean the following: At the beginning of my document I have the abstract, acknowledgment, list of content, list of figures and list of tables. Each of this has a heading, i.e. a title, for example "abstract". The problem now is that this titles are all not left aligned, i.e. they are indented but I would like it to have left aligned. This only happens when adding this special chapter / section layout.

Comment: There is just another last problem: subsections and subsusetions are not in the special new layout. How can I made this too?

Comment: The MWE is the Minimal Working Example you provided. So your original LaTeX Code. Here is some more information on how to write a good MWE: [http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that]. I asked to extend yours as there is no abstract environment for example in the scrbook class. So I wanted to know how you added it. Nevertheless I think I understand what you mean. I updated my code.

Comment: I also added the code for the subsections. It's mostly just copy&paste. So you should be able to adjust the code for the subsubsections by yourself. But in my opinion thats all too much. At the subsection level or at least at the subsubsections level I would use a simpler design.

Comment: Thank you again, now everything is great. How would you change the design for the subsection or subsubsection level? If I just change to the title (black) it looks a bit strange when I have the other style for the sections.

Comment: I updated my example for the `subsubsections`.