# Placing a rule in a custom section title (scrbook)

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

Starting from the accepted answer of

[Customizing chapter and section style (scrbook)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288737/customizing-chapter-and-section-style-scrbook)

I did the following to get customized section titles in a scrbook
(Minimal (not) Working Example):

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newlength{\sectsquaresize}
\setlength\sectsquaresize{70pt}

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}

\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\color{black}}


\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
    \parbox{\sectsquaresize}{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}%
  \fbox{\colorbox{yellow}{%
      \parbox[m][\dimexpr \sectsquaresize -  2 \fboxrule][c]{\dimexpr \sectsquaresize - 2 \fboxrule}%
                {\centering{\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}}}}}}%
    \quad%  
    }



\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \par\nobreak%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{\sectsquaresize}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\sectsquaresize}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\sectionproc}[1]{\parbox[m][\sectsquaresize][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth - \sectsquaresize - 17pt}{\raggedright #1}}
\newcommand{\ltdis}[1]{#1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Erkrankungen des Bewegungsapparats}

\section[Rheumatoide Arthritis]{\sectionproc{Rheumatoide Arthritis\newline\ltdis{Arthritis rheumatoides}}}

\blindtext


\section[Rheumatismus]{\sectionproc{Rheumatismus\newline\ltdis{Rheumatismus}}}

\blindtext


\section[Arthrose mit besonderer Deformation der Gelenke]{\sectionproc{Arthrose mit besonderer Deformation der Gelenke\newline\ltdis{Arthrosis deformans, spondylosis deformans}}}

\blindtext


\section[Händezittern]{\sectionproc{Händezittern\newline\ltdis{Tendovaginitis}}}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

In the output, the horizontal `\rule`, which starts horizontally after the framed yellow square and ends at the textline end, is vertically not aligned to the lower black frame line of the yellow square (as I wished it should be).

[image: first page of text]

I tried to introduce `\vspace*{[a negative value]}` after `\par\nobreak` to remedy this, but could not find a suitable expression which works in all cases.

```
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \par\nobreak%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{\sectsquaresize}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\sectsquaresize}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
```

What could I do to get the \rule aligned with the lower black frame line of the yellow square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following does what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}% scalable font

\newlength{\sectsquaresize}
\setlength\sectsquaresize{70pt}

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont}%<- changed
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\color{black}}%<- changed

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}%
  \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{%
    \parbox[m][\dimexpr \sectsquaresize - 2 \fboxrule][c]{\dimexpr \sectsquaresize - 2 \fboxrule}%
       {\centering{\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}}}}%
  \quad%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth+\dp\strutbox\relax}{%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{%
        \parbox[m][\sectsquaresize][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth - \sectsquaresize - 17pt}{\raggedsection #4}%
      }}%
    }%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}%
    }{%
      \hspace*{\sectsquaresize}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\sectsquaresize}{1pt}%
    }%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}% original definition for other section levels
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ltdis}[1]{#1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Erkrankungen des Bewegungsapparats}
\section[Rheumatoide Arthritis]{Rheumatoide Arthritis\newline\ltdis{Arthritis rheumatoides}}
\blindtext
\section[Rheumatismus]{Rheumatismus\newline\ltdis{Rheumatismus}}
\blindtext
\section[Arthrose mit besonderer Deformation der Gelenke]{Arthrose mit besonderer Deformation der Gelenke\newline\ltdis{Arthrosis deformans, spondylosis deformans}}
\blindtext
\section[Händezittern]{Händezittern\newline\ltdis{Tendovaginitis}}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your code worked very well! If I see it right, the essence of your idea was to put the \@hangfrom{..#2..#3}{..#4..} stuff alltogether in a \makebox of width zero, raise this box and place a ruler under the raised box where necessary. So the solution also solves the general problem how to put a ruler under the content of a \makebox.