# Customize chapter and section style in appendices

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script, scrbook

I am using the `scrbook` document class. I would like to change the style of chapters and sections in the **Appendices** as illustrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288920). It works very well except for the word *Chapter* in the black rectangle when `\appendix` is utilized. How to change the word to *Appendix* accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\chaptername` by `\chapapp` and add option `numbers=noenddot`.¹

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}% <- changed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblueii}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\itshape\rmfamily\small\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \parbox[b][60pt]{45pt}{\centering%
      {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chapapp}}% <- changed
      \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter}}% <- changed
      \vspace{6pt}%
}}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \raisebox{-4pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \enskip\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}\enskip}%
  \quad%
}}

\renewcommand\subsectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \raisebox{-4pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
    \enskip\usekomafont{subsectionnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot}\enskip}%
  \quad%
}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-5pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}}%
  \@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{Section Title}
\blindtext
\addsec{Unnumbered Section Title}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\appendix% <- added
\chapter{Appendix Chapter Title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

¹ Note that I have changed my linked answer too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. However, when I add the code snippets into my existing preamble, the word `Chapter` doesn't show up in the rectangle for each chapter due to some interference somehow. I post it in another thread [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642485/missing-chapter-when-using-chapapp). Could you please kindly help me solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I should also note that your solution is added to the **bottom** of my preamble in the linked MWE above.