# beautiful section styles

Tags: sectioning, formatting, tikz-styles

I came across to website of [IREM](http://www.univ-irem.fr/lexique/co/site.html) which I found beautiful section style in the following file [Original file](http://www.univ-irem.fr/lexique/res/ft10-Les_curseurs.pdf)  was created with PDFLaTeX.

Could someone please create those styles for sections and subsections with Latex

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Plya's Problem-Solving Cycle}
\subsection{Understand the problem}
\subsection{Devise a Plan}
\subsection{Carry Out the Plan}
\subsection{Look Back}
\section{Second Section}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Sections_and_chapters, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288966,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292001or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301185

Comment: The [original file](http://www.univ-irem.fr/lexique/res/ft10-Les_curseurs.pdf) (founded by googling the file name) was created with PDFLaTeX. Probably the best thing to do is to try to contact the authors (look at the [IREM website](http://www.univ-irem.fr/lexique/co/site.html)).

Comment: Yes, I know I took it from there, but don't forget that in this community there are many capable people who can do better than those authors.

Comment: @Educ It would be helpful if you post the source if it's known. That saves the people time and effort and shows respect to the original author.

Comment: Okay I'll do that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answer based on `titlesec` and `soul`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{titleblue}{HTML}{4a7aa4}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\newbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[1]
  {%
    \bgroup
    \setbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox\hbox{\colorbox{titleblue}\strut}%
    \setul{\dimexpr\dp\TitleUnderlineTestBox-.3ex\relax}{.3ex}%
    \ul{#1}%
    \egroup
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBox[1]
  {%
    \colorbox{titleblue}
      {%
        \makebox[2.5em][c]
          {%
            \color{white}%
            \strut
            \csname the#1\endcsname
          }%
      }%
    \TitleUnderline{\ \ \ }%
  }
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{section}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{subsection}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Plya's Problem-Solving Cycle}
\subsection{Understand the problem}
\subsection{Devise a Plan}
\subsection{Carry Out the Plan}
\subsection{Look Back}
\section{Second Section}

\section
  {Really long section name that is really long, so long it takes two rows}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I should consider `soul` more often :). How did you come up with `\setul{.97ex}{.3ex}` (the exact values)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner to be honest: trial and error. Latest edit only has `.3ex` as a "guessed" value (which I think looks good -- one could change that).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner honesty is good for the soul

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perfect play on words.

Comment: I tired to add \includegraphics[width=1cm]{1.jpg} inside the section but it's gives me error

Comment: @Educ you mean in the argument of `\section`? Don't do that. Ever. Is that picture supposed to end up in the page's header/footer and ToC, too?

Comment: yes because I want to Illustrate some command of geogebra that's why I have to add picture of tools in argument of \section and subsection

Comment: @Educ though I explicitly don't recommend this: If you don't use a ToC, you can include an image in the section's title by using `\section{\protect\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}`.

Comment: I would like to use ToC

Comment: Should I post new question ?

Comment: @Educ turns out using `\protect` does also work if you use a ToC. But I get another error from my code as soon as I use `\tableofcontents`. I'll investigate. Asking a new question might be a good idea though.

Comment: @Educ please ask a new question. There seem to be more issues than I thought in combination of `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429490/error-adding-includegraphics-in-argument-of-section-or-subsection-with-tableofc

Comment: Please edit my english in my above question to be clear

Comment: very nice :) and beautifully indented source code

Comment: @cmhughes thanks, coding style is important for readability.

Comment: Could you add code which will fix the bibliography header? Right now it just appears as a box.

Comment: @IsomorphicTwin Could you please add a follow up question which references this answer? The solution might be dependent on the used bibliography packages.

Comment: @Skillmon I've asked a separate question and included the code here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476173/title-formatting-the-section-makes-the-bibliography-header-disappear?noredirect=1#comment1201961_476173