# Error: adding includegraphics in argument of section or subsection with tableofcontents

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting

I'm using the following code   but when I want to add `\includegraphics{example-image-duck}` to argument of section or subsection I got error in this case @Skillmon suggest to add `\protect` which gives `\section{\protect\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}` but even though I got error besides I get another error from that code as soon as I use \tableofcontents.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{titleblue}{HTML}{4a7aa4}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\newbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[1]
  {%
    \bgroup
    \setbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox\hbox{\colorbox{titleblue}\strut}%
    \setul{\dimexpr\dp\TitleUnderlineTestBox-.3ex\relax}{.3ex}%
    \ul{#1}%
    \egroup
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBox[1]
  {%
    \colorbox{titleblue}
      {%
        \makebox[2.5em][c]
          {%
            \color{white}%
            \strut
            \csname the#1\endcsname
          }%
      }%
    \TitleUnderline{\ \ \ }%
  }
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{section}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{subsection}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lenny}
\chapter{Lenny}
\section{Use this Tools \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck} to obtain random points in Geogebra}
\section{Plya's Problem-Solving Cycle}
\subsection{Understand the problem}
\subsection{Devise a Plan}
\subsection{Carry Out the Plan}
\subsection{Look Back}
\section{Second Section}

\section
  {Really long section name that is really long, so long it takes two rows}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No need to load `graphics` if you then load `graphicx`.

Comment: `\protect\includegraphics` works fine for me. But you should delete the old toc.

Comment: works fine with `\protect\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer funny. I used `article` in my tests (because the first question was using `article`), and there I get the error `! Argument of \@mkboth has an extra }.`. As soon as I use `report` everything works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but there still is an issue as soon as you use `\protect\includegraphics`. Compilation works, but the line under the caption ends at the image.

Comment: @Skillmon you could get the correct line by adding a \mbox around the graphics (to hide it from soul). But with article it will fail for the \section inside \tableofcontents. I would never use soul here -- much too fragile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, it is fragile. How would you create that style? One could use Ti*k*Z I guess. Multi-line underlining isn't TeX's strength it seems.

Comment: In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476188/117050 there is a version of this, that uses `ulem` instead of `soul` which should be more robust (at the expense of worse on screen display and breaking automatic hyphenation). Just for anybody interested in it.