# Title formatting the section makes the bibliography header disappear

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I used a section style that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429441/beautiful-section-styles).
The problem is that the header of the bibliography becomes a box even though I've tried to make a separate style for unnumbered sections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{titleblue}{HTML}{4a7aa4}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\newbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[1]
  {%
    \bgroup
    \setbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox\hbox{\colorbox{titleblue}\strut}%
    \setul{\dimexpr\dp\TitleUnderlineTestBox-.3ex\relax}{.3ex}%
    \ul{#1}%
    \egroup
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBox[1]
  {%
    \colorbox{titleblue}
      {%
        \makebox[2.5em][c]
          {%
            \color{white}%
            \strut
            \csname the#1\endcsname
          }%
      }%
    \TitleUnderline{\ \ \ }%
  }
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{section}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{subsection}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{The First Section}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Edit: This is the error message that shows up:

> I came across hyphenatable material enclosed in group braces, which I
>   can't handle. Either drop the braces or make the material unbreakable
>   using an \mbox (\hbox). Note that a space also counts as possible
>   hyphenation point. See page 4 of the manual. I'm leaving a black
>   square so that you can see where I am right now.

Comment: This code is not compilable, and has no formatting for unnumbered sections.

Comment: Your MWE misses a `\end{thebibliography}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Even if it's included, I still get a blue box instead of "References".

Comment: @Bernard `\section*{Foo}` does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems the unexpanded name of the section (if I'm not mistaken). The following completely expands the given name with an `\edef` expansion (this might produce new issues, I'm not sure). It however works for your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{titleblue}{HTML}{4a7aa4}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\newbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[1]
  {%
    \bgroup
    \setbox\TitleUnderlineTestBox\hbox{\colorbox{titleblue}\strut}%
    \setul{\dimexpr\dp\TitleUnderlineTestBox-.3ex\relax}{.3ex}%
    \edef\mytmp{#1}%
    \expandafter\ul\expandafter{\mytmp}%
    \egroup
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBox[1]
  {%
    \colorbox{titleblue}
      {%
        \makebox[2.5em][c]
          {%
            \color{white}%
            \strut
            \csname the#1\endcsname
          }%
      }%
    \TitleUnderline{\ \ \ }%
  }
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{section}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
  {\SectionNumberBox{subsection}}
  {0pt}
  {\TitleUnderline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{The First Section}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

## Alternative

The following defines an alternative style, that formats unnumbered sections similar to the numbered ones (it uses `report` and also defines `\chapter` to be matching, just remove that and you're good to go with `article`). It also removes the unnecessary repetition of calling `\titleformat` for each sectioning level by defining a shorthand macro.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{titleblue}{HTML}{4a7aa4}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\newlength\SectionNumberBoxPad
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \setul{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\fboxsep-.3ex\relax}{.3ex}%
      \edef\mytmp{#1}%
      \expandafter\ul\expandafter{\mytmp}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBoxSep{\TitleUnderline{\ \ \ }}
\newcommand*\UnnumberedSectionNumberBox
  {%
    \colorbox{titleblue}
      {\strut\hspace{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}%
    \SectionNumberBoxSep
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBox[1]
  {%
    \colorbox{titleblue}
      {%
        \begingroup
        \color{white}%
        \setlength\SectionNumberBoxPad{.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}%
        \hspace{\SectionNumberBoxPad}%
        \strut\csname the#1\endcsname
        \hspace{\SectionNumberBoxPad}%
        \endgroup
      }%
    \SectionNumberBoxSep
  }
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setuptitleformat[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\setuptitleformat@\csname #1\endcsname{#1}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand*\setuptitleformat@[3]
  {%
    \titleformat{#1}
      {#3\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
      {\SectionNumberBox{#2}}
      {0pt}
      {\TitleUnderline{##1}}%
    \titleformat{name=#1,numberless}
      {#3\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
      {\UnnumberedSectionNumberBox}
      {0pt}
      {\TitleUnderline{##1}}%
  }
\makeatother
\setuptitleformat{chapter}{\LARGE}
\setuptitleformat{section}{\Large}
\setuptitleformat{subsection}{\large}
\setuptitleformat{subsubsection}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{The First Subsection}
\subsubsection{The First Subsubsection}
Some text

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Alternative 2

This version should look identical in print, but the display of the PDF depends on the viewer (xpdf can be trusted, though; this is because using `ulem` the lines are built using small segments which might lead to aliasing issues on screens). It breaks automatic hyphenation, but remains line breakable. It uses the `ulem` package instead of the `soul` package. `ulem` should be robuster, and therefore the `\edef` expansion is not needed with it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\definecolor{titleblue}{HTML}{4a7aa4}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Educ}
\date{\today}

\newlength\SectionNumberBoxPad
\newlength\TitleUnderlineSeg
\setlength\TitleUnderlineSeg{.05pt}
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[1]
  {%
    \bgroup
    \markoverwith
      {%
        \rule
          [-\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\fboxsep\relax]
          {\TitleUnderlineSeg}
          {.3ex}%
      }%
    \ULon{#1}%
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBoxSep
  {%
    \hspace{-\TitleUnderlineSeg}%
    \TitleUnderline
      {\hspace{\TitleUnderlineSeg}\hspace{\SectionNumberBoxPad}}%
  }
\newcommand*\UnnumberedSectionNumberBox
  {%
    \begingroup
      \setlength\SectionNumberBoxPad{.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}%
      \colorbox{titleblue}
        {\strut\hspace{2\SectionNumberBoxPad}}%
      \SectionNumberBoxSep
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand*\SectionNumberBox[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \setlength\SectionNumberBoxPad{.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}%
      \colorbox{titleblue}
        {%
          \begingroup
          \color{white}%
          \hspace{\SectionNumberBoxPad}%
          \strut\csname the#1\endcsname
          \hspace{\SectionNumberBoxPad}%
          \endgroup
        }%
      \SectionNumberBoxSep
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setuptitleformat[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\setuptitleformat@\csname #1\endcsname{#1}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand*\setuptitleformat@[3]
  {%
    \titleformat{#1}
      {#3\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
      {\SectionNumberBox{#2}}
      {0pt}
      {\TitleUnderline{##1}}%
    \titleformat{name=#1,numberless}
      {#3\bfseries\sffamily\color{titleblue}}
      {\UnnumberedSectionNumberBox}
      {0pt}
      {\TitleUnderline{##1}}%
  }
\makeatother
\setuptitleformat{chapter}{\LARGE}
\setuptitleformat{section}{\Large}
\setuptitleformat{subsection}{\large}
\setuptitleformat{subsubsection}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{The First Subsection}
\subsubsection{The First Subsubsection}
Some text
\section
  {Really long section name that is really long, so long it takes two rows}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*The lines do align vertically with the box of the section numbers (checked with `xpdf` at 2000% magnification), the mismatch is due to Gimp's rasterization.*