# Change the chapter and section style

Tags: chapters, titlesec, section-titles

I'm using `titlesec` package to have a good style of the chapters and sections title. But now,
I would like to add a colored box around the chapter number and section number, I want to get the same style as the photo attached but I don't know how to do this. I prepared an example of what I'm using.

I'm using texshop.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,english]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\linespread{1.3} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The standard Model and beyond}
\section{The Standard Model of Particle physics}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related (basically, exactly what you want for `\section`, but not for `\chapter`): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429441/beautiful-section-styles/429453#429453

Comment: Why do you use `fncychap`?

Comment: Also, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476173/title-formatting-the-section-makes-the-bibliography-header-disappear?noredirect=1#comment1201961_476173 (the solutions suggested have their limitations).

Comment: If you're using LuaLaTeX one could also use `lua-ul` which should be more robust than `soul` and `ulem`.