# Page styles with Koma instead of titlesec

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, titlesec

I usually set up my page style `titlesec` along the lines of

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{
  \headrule
  \sethead{Document Title}{\sectiontitle}{\pagename\space\thepage}
  \setfoot{Some Static Info}{Author}{Other Static Info}
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
```

But now I read that there are [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec). Although I did not notice those incompatibilities, I am a little concerned.

Is there a way to define the page style without using `titlesec`, but still keep it as clear and powerful?

Comment: Very interesting question.

Comment: »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« has its own package »scrlayer-scrpage« (or the older »scrpage2«) to set up page styles. It is *preferable over any other package* here since it cooperates best with the classes from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)«. The package has its own chapter in the user guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an approach that should get you started. The details can be found in Chapter 6 of the »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« user guide.

```
\documentclass[headinclude=on]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{section}
\ihead{Document Title}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{Page\enspace\pagemark}
\ifoot{Some Static Info}
\cfoot{Author}
\ofoot{Other Static Info}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, the »[blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)« package is only for creating the dummy document to make the page style visible. It is *not* part of the solution.

Comment: The information for the document title and the author could be taken from the corresponding commands for `\maketitle` (if desired).

Comment: This only works with Koma script v3.12 or later, i.e. starting with _TeXLive2013_. I am on _TeXLive2012_, but replacing `scrlayer-scrpage` with `scrpage2` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The commands `\sethead` and `\setfoot` from package `titlesec` or its component `titleps` map to several `scrlayer-scrpage` commands, e.g.:

```
\newcommand\sethead[3]{\ihead{#1}\chead{#2}\ohead{#3}}
\newcommand\setfoot[3]{\ifoot{#1}\cfoot{#2}\ofoot{#3}}
```

The `\headrule` command should be similar to this:

```
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.4pt}
```

Comment: The definition of a new command makes sense if this command is used used very often in the document, but not for the once used setup of the page style.

Comment: That’s right, of course. I just wanted to show the different concepts by example. Nevertheless, one could define such commands in a custom `.sty` to avoid learning new things, I guess. Actually, I first tried to reimplement all of `titleps` with KOMA-Script macros, but at some point gave up.