# How to emulate titlesec commands in KOMA-Script?

Tags: koma-script, titlesec

Could we create a `titlesec` to `KOMA-script` lexicon?
Or, in other words, how to emulate `titlesec` commands with native `KOMA` ones?

The point would be to define *"`\titleseccommand[<a>]{<b>}{<c>}` is emulated by `\KOMAcommand1{<b>}\KOMAcommand2{<c>}{<a>}`"* for each `titlesec` commands.

---

### Background

*[`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) is a great package to easily customize your titles. 
[`KOMA-script`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes are great too.*

*However, [there are incompatibilities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec) between `KOMA` classes and `titlesec`.
Even if the clash is not crippling in most cases, you still get this nice warning:*

> ```
> Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
> (scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
> (scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use the package only
> (scrartcl)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
> (scrartcl)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
> (scrartcl)              the extended optional argument of the section
> (scrartcl)              commands .
> ```

*Indeed, `KOMA` classes have their own commands to pimp your titles.
You thus find here several questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159781/page-styles-with-koma-instead-of-titlesec), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298491/replace-titlesec-chapter-style-with-koma), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288737/customizing-chapter-and-section-style-scrbook), etc.) asking to "translate" a personnalized title/heading using `titlesec` macros into `KOMA-script` native commands.*

*Since there are only case-specific answers, it is hard to generalize and adapt to your own problem.*

---

### Material

Here is a sum-up of `titlesec` commands and options.

- **`\titlelabel{<A:label-format>}`**

Defines what is printed as label (~number) for `(sub)sections`. E.g. to add an em dash (`---`) after the section number (`\thesection`)): `\titlelabel{\thesection---\quad}`

- **`\titleformat*{<B:sectionning-command>}{<C:format>}`**

(Light-version of `\titleformat`) Changes the *format* (`\itshape`, `\bfseries`...) of a *sectionning command* (`\title`, `\section`...). E.g. to make paragraph titles bold : `\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries}`

- **`\titleformat{D:command}[E:shape]{F:format}{G:label}{H:sep}{I:before-code}{J:after-code}`**
  Redefines the "internal" format of a title (i.e. how it looks -- fontshape, label, etc.).
  Here are the arguments of options:

  - *D:command* : a sectionning command (`\part`,`\section`, etc.)
  - *E:shape* : `hang`, `block`, `display`, `runin`, `leftmargin`, `fightmargin`, `drop`, or `wrap`. See definition in [titlesec documentation](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), p. 3.
  - *F:format* : text layout of the label and the title (e.g. `\bfseries`, `\itshape`)
  - *G:label* : defines what is printed as label (~number). E.g. to add an em dash after the section number `{\thesection---\quad}`
  - *H:sep* : the horizontalspace between  the label and the title. Must be a length (`2em`, `1cm`, `.1\linewidth`...) (Defined differently for `display`, and `frame` shapes.)
  - *I:before-code* : code executed before the title body. (E.g. for a text shape different than the label's one)
  - *J:after-code* : code executed after the title body.
- **`\titlespacing{K:command}{L:left}{M:before-sep}{N:after-sep}[O:right-sep]`** 
  Redefines the "external" format of a title (i.e. how it is regarding the rest of the text -- indentation, spacing, etc.). The starred version (`\titlespacing*`) kills the indentation of the text following the paragraph.
  Here are the argument options

  - *K:command* : a sectionning command (`\part`,`\section`, etc.)
  - *L:left* : increases the left margin
  - *M:before-sep* : vertical space before the title (e.g. `2\parskip`)
  - *N:after-sep* : vertical (or horizontal regarding the shape used) space after the title (e.g. `5pc plus 2pt minus 3pt`).
  - *O:right-sep* : increases the right-sep margin in case of using `hang`, `block` of `diplay` shape.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of KOMA (replacing every LaTeX command with a different name)? ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not really a answer to the question. I think it is not possible to "translate" the `titlesec` commands in a *general way* to KOMA-Script commands. They are using different approaches. So here is only an overview of some possible ways.

The relevant KOMA-Script commands and options are

- `\RedeclareSectionCommand`, `\RedeclareSectionCommands`, `\DeclareSectionCommand` etc.
- `\partformat`, `\chapterformat`, `\sectionformat` etc.
- `\raggedchapter` and  `\raggedsection`
- `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomatfont`
- `chapterprefix` and `appendixprefix`
- `headings=<value>` with a `<value>` like `big`, `normal`, `small`, `onelineappendix`, `twolineappendix`, `onelinechapter`, `twolinechapter` etc.
- `\sectionlinesformat`, `\sectioncatchphraseformat`, `\chapterlinesformat` and `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`

See the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) for more informations.

---

**`\titlelabel`** (from package `titlesec`)

You can redefine the KOMA-Script commands `\partformat`, `\chapterformat`, `\sectionformat` etc. Example:

```
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\thesection\autodot\enskip}
```

---

**`\titleformat*`** (from package `titlesec`)

Use KOMA-Script commands `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` or `\RedeclareSectionCommand` or `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the font settings for section headings. Note that font element `dispostion` is used for all section levels before their own font element. The settings of `disposition` can only be changed with `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`. Examples:

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\mdseries\large]{section}
```

---

**`\titlespacing`** (from package `titlesec`)

Use options `indent` (not available for `part` and `chapter` styles), `beforeskip` and `afterskip` of commands `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands`. Examples:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[indent=2em]{section,subsection}
```

Note there are more options for these commands like `font`, `level`, `style`, `counterwithin`, `prefixfont`, `innerskip` etc. depending on option `style` that could be `section`, `chapter` or `part`.

If you want to change the right margin (and/or the left margin of chapters and parts) you have to redefine `\sectionlinesformat`, `\chapterlinesformat` or `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`.

---

**`\titleformat`** (from package `titlesec`)

You have to use a combination of commands mentioned in the list above. This combination depends for a example from the desired shape. So I think this could not be answered in a short general way. Here are only some possibilities.

- shape like hang: Default layout for chapter, section, subsection and subsubsection headings. To change paragraph and subparagraph headings to `hang` set a positive value to option `afterskip` by using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. Example: `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{paragraph}`. Then you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` or `\chapterlinesformat`.
- shape like runin: Default layout for paragraph and subparagraph. To change other headings (with `style=section`) to `runin` set a negative value to option `afterskip` using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. Example:`\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-1em]{subsubsection}`. Then you can redefine `\sectioncatchphraseformat`. If you want to change the shape of chapter heading to a `runin` like you have to set its `style` to `section`.
- shape like display: Default layout for headings with `style=part`. To use a prefix line for chapters set option `chapterprefixline` or `headings=twolinechapter`. Note that you can switch the prefix line for appendix chapters separatly by option `appendixprefixline` or `headings=twolinechapter` etc. Then you can redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. If you want to use a twoline heading for other section levels one possibility is redefining `\sectionlinesformat`.

Note that the `style` option of a section level can be changed using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. Example: `\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}`

Shapes block, frame, leftmargin and rightmargin should be also possible by redefining `\sectionlinesformat`, `\sectioncatchphraseformat`, `\chapterlinesformat` and/or `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`.

Comment: If you want to execute code after or before the sectioning title, redefine the appropriate `linesformat`