# Chapter title format back to default

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, titlesec

I messed with various chapter title formats and now that I want to go back to default i.e

```
Chapter 1

Title
```

I only get

```
1.Title
```

which misses "Chapter 1" appearing before the chapter title. I tried to use titlesec like this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{%
\chaptertitlename\ \achapter
}{20pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}%
```

It does look similar but not the same. How can I go back to default? I am using scrbook

Comment: I wonder a little bit about that `\achapter` statement.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

The normal behavior with `scrbook` is not the one you've mentioned, but this one:

[image]

obtained with

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

I think you want `scrbook` to simulate the standard `book` class.

Using `titlesec`, which is not completely advised when using KOMA classes, you can obtain something similar (respecting the font used in KOMA classes) with the following definition:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The right way with `scrbook` is to load it with the option `chapterprefix=true`, as stated in [Thorsten's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160961/27635).

If you want to obtain almost exactly the same format as in the `book` class, you can add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip.5\baselineskip}
  {\vskip20pt}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{50pt}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{50pt}}

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip.5\baselineskip}
  {\vskip20pt}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{50pt}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{50pt}}

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Regarding `titlesec`: From your user profile and avatar I see you live on Sardinia. But your name lets me tempt to assume you understand German, so take a look on [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36310). With recent KOMA-Script one will get a warning. (I see your remark in your answer.)

Comment: @Speravir No, I don't understand a word of German... And I perfectly know that one should never use `titlesec` with KOMA classes.

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarification. With your name you should learn … ;-)

Comment: @Speravir In fact it's not my real name :-)

Comment: Oh, you are mean, ;-) Back to topic: `titlesec` works partially, one has to test. The problem I see is, that a function that works now maybe not work in a future release of KOMA-Script.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on this chapter prefix by loading the class with the `chapterprefix` option. For details please have a look at the »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« user guide.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: The »[blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)« package is only used here to create the dummy document. It is not part of the solution.

Comment: +1 I was to add it in my answer. However, I can't find a way to increase the spacing between the chapter number and the chapter title

Comment: @karlkoeller: I can't see where this should be necessary here.

Comment: Just for my knowlegde.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Ask a corresponding question.

Comment: I've found it by myself...