# Width of \chapter section with titlesec

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec

I use the `titlesec` package for styling the sectioning commands. But I have a problem with the chapter width or right margin:

[image: Chapter Title]

The width of the text should only reach to the blue line, "Organisation" and "Display" should break. I know `\\` is an option, but in the footer is also the chapter name referred:

[image]

So, if I use `\\`, the text in the footer is: "Konzepte für die semantische"...

The styling ist:

```
% > formats: \chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\usekomafont{chapter}}%
{\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
}%
{-2.1em}%
{\raggedright}%
[\phantomsection]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that, even if you introduce a \\ in your title, it will be converted to space in your header/footer with the `newlinetospace` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `explicit` option for titlesec to place the title inside a `\parbox` of the desired length; notice that now you need to use `#1` (typically in the last mandatory argument for `\titleformat`) to get the title for the sectional unit. I used `\textwidth-3em` as the width for the box, but you can change this value according to your needs. In the example below I provided some definitions for the colors used since they were not given in the question:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}%
  [\phantomsection]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** has pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165878/width-of-chapter-section-with-titlesec/165884?noredirect=1#comment381055_165884), one can avoid using the `explicit` option using an auxiliary macro:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
  [\phantomsection]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I added `\sectfont` to your definitions so you can keep the boldfaced sansseerf font used by default in KOMA sectional units:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}\sectfont}%
  {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
  [\phantomsection]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `titlesec` and KOMA-Script might not be fully compatible (you'll get a warning from the KOMA classes when loading `titlesec`); see [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954)

Comment: `explicit` is not necessary; the last token in the relevant argument of `\titleformat` can be a macro taking an argument, so you can just say `\mychapformat` defining `\newcommand{\mychapformat}[1]{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}`.

Comment: @egreg Ah, that's nice. I've added your suggetion to my answer. Thanks you.