# How to show a long chapter name in the footer with two lines?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

A short time ago, I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165878/width-of-chapter-section-with-titlesec) to resize the width of a chapter section.

But there is another problem with the footer. If the chapter name is too long, the chapter name in the footer ends in the middle. Is there any possibility to make the height optimal for two lines?

[image: Chapter name]

[image: Footer]

I tried to make a working sample, but it's not optimal...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{tgheros}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
  [\phantomsection]

% **************************************************
% Header and Footer
% **************************************************
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{%
        \footnotesize%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\textbf{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}%
        \quad%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}#1}%
    }{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{%
        \footnotesize%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\textbf{\thesection}}%
        \quad%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}#1}%
    }%
}
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }\usekomafont{chapter}%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{ctcolorchapterline}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \usekomafont{chapter}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{ctcolorchapterline}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%
\fancypagestyle{maincontentstyle}{%
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }\usekomafont{chapter}\footnotesize%
        \rightmark%
        \hspace*{0.75cm}{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{ctcolorfooterpage}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \usekomafont{chapter}\footnotesize%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{ctcolorchapterline}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \footnotesize%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{0.75cm}\leftmark%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That example produces rather odd results for me. I get no title at all in the footer and the chapter title itself goes over the blue line, while the chapter number is displayed as 'size60601'. Please make sure that your code really demonstrates the issue you are concerned with.

Comment: I noticed a warning not to combine Koma font with fancyhdr.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I didn't change that stuff but this is almost certainly not the best way to do this given the facilities offered by the Koma classes.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

[image: Footer - multiline]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{layout}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
  [\phantomsection]

% **************************************************
% Header and Footer
% **************************************************
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{%
        \footnotesize%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\textbf{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}%
        \quad%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}#1}%
    }{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{%
        \footnotesize%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\textbf{\thesection}}%
        \quad%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}#1}%
    }%
}
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }\usekomafont{chapter}%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{ctcolorchapterline}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \usekomafont{chapter}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{ctcolorchapterline}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%
\newlength{\mychapbox}
\setlength{\mychapbox}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\mychapbox}{-1.5em}
\addtolength{\mychapbox}{-0.75cm}
\addtolength{\mychapbox}{-10pt}
\fancypagestyle{maincontentstyle}{%
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }\usekomafont{chapter}\footnotesize%
        \rightmark%
        \hspace*{0.75cm}{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{ctcolorfooterpage}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \usekomafont{chapter}\footnotesize%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{ctcolorchapterline}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \footnotesize%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{0.75cm}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\mychapbox}%
            \raggedleft\usekomafont{chapter}\color{ctcolorchapterline}\footnotesize\leftmark%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
}
\pagestyle{maincontentstyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```