# How to have the complete title into the footer of cleanthesis style?

Tags: header-footer, cleanthesis

I use cleanthesis style and i have a problem with the chapter's title into the footer that is cut because it is too long. Is there an alternative to have the complete title maybe on two lines maybe ?

Somebody have asked the same question but the solution seems to be cumbersome and has not been validated : [How to show a long chapter name in the footer with two lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168582/how-to-show-a-long-chapter-name-in-the-footer-with-two-lines)

My code

```
 \documentclass[%
    paper=A4,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,               % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,                  % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=full,               % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
    12pt,                       % font size
    headings=normal,            % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,                % value for draft version
]{scrbook}%
\usepackage[                    % clean thesis style
    figuresep=colon,%
    sansserif=true,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,% position
    hangsection=false,% position
    hangsubsection=false,% position
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
    bibsys=bibtex,% biber
    bibfile=bib-refs,%
    bibstyle=authoryear,%
]{cleanthesis}
\chapter{A very long title with How to have the complete title into the footer of cleanthesis style? Any ideas ?}
```

and I obtain

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example so that we can test?

Comment: @Troy i put an example with a part of my code and a picture

Comment: Can you make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Just use the optional argument: `\chapter[footer title]{Long title seen at the start of the chapter}`