# Recreate a chapter style

Tags: chapters

How can I recreate this particular style for both chapters and sections?

[image: Chapter]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You should take a look at `titlesec`.

Comment: Here's something similar to what you'd want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165884/213149

Answer (score 1):

The code below will at least get you close, but you should investigate the [titlesec package's documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for more details, or consult the capabilities of your document class.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% font like picture
\usepackage{titlesec}

% style chapters
\titleformat{\chapter}% sectioning command to format
    [block]% shape of chapter titles = number next to title
    {}% common formatting to number and title
    {{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\bfseries\thechapter}% scaled bold chapter number
        \hspace*{0.7em}\rule[2pt]{1.3pt}{6\baselineskip}}% vertical line
    {0.7em}% space between number and title
    {\Large\MakeUppercase}% style applied to title
% (use * after \titlespacing to unindent next paragraph)
\titlespacing{\chapter}% set spacing for chapter titles
    {0pt}% no space to left
    {0pt}% no space to above
    {\baselineskip}% skip one line afterwards

% style sections
\titleformat{\section}% sectioning command to format
    [block]% shape: number then title
    {\bfseries}% make both number and title bold
    {\thesection.}% number followed by period
    {0.5em}% space between number and title
    {\MakeUppercase}% style of title
\titlespacing{\section}% set spacing for section titles
    {0pt}% no space to left
    {1.4\baselineskip}% space above
    {0.6\baselineskip}% space below

\begin{document}

\chapter{General Thermodynamic Properties}

Text here.

\section{Extensive and Intensive Properties}

More text here. 

\end{document}
```

[image]