# I'd like to have blue boxes for the main parts of my work (toc, introduction, chapter, conclusion et references)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's what I've done:

```
\ovalbox{\colorbox{cyan!26}{ 
%   \begin{minipage}{15cm} 
%           \large
%               \centering
%               \vspace{0.1cm}
%       \textbf{INTRODUCTION GENERALE }
%   \end{minipage} 
%}}
%\end{center}
```

It works only for text, but not for sections, chapters and so on.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It is the [policy](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/687/non-english-questions) of this site and [stack overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684) in general that questions be in English. If you could translate yours then you will be much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Maybe the answers to this similar question may help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179019/118712

Comment: As it stands what you have currently won't compile unless you remove the `%` and put `\usepackage{xcolor}`. If you could make a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) then you will be more likely to get help.

Comment: Hello kaldor and welcome. La langue à employer sur TeX-SE est l'anglais, afin que tout le monde vous comprenne et puisse vous aider ;)

Comment: Merci bien j'ai consulter le guide de démarrage .

Comment: Merci pour votre solution : tex.stackexchange.com/q/179019/118712 – Markus G.   Mais moi je voudrais avoir des boîtes arrondies.

Comment: Sorry for not removing the%.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, which is basically a combination of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568900/118712 and this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389833/118712

I also added some modifications for your re-naming of the toc and bib chapter titles.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=totocnumbered]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[width=17.00cm, height=23.00cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace} \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Références bibliographiques}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \tcbox[on line, boxsep=4pt,left=4pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,colframe=blue,colback=cyan!26,arc=5mm]{
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\raggedchapter
            \@hangfrom{\strut#2}{#3}%
        }%
    }%
}

\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \tcbox[on line, boxsep=4pt,left=4pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,colframe=green,colback=red,arc=5mm]{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{\strut\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
        }%
    }%
}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document} 
    \tableofcontents
    \addchap[Introduction generale]{\scshape Introduction} 
    \addsec{I -- contexte et justification } 
    \addsec{objectifs} 
    \chapter{début} 
    \section{title}
\end{document}
```

[image]