# Section title with runin and KOMA-Script class?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec, scrartcl

I would like to have section titles with runin so that there is no newline after the section title. This can be done with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{\section}[runin]{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}[]
\begin{document}
    \section{First section}
     This text follows on the same line as "First section"
\end{document}
```

However, I am using the KOMA-Script `scrartcl` class and use of the `titlesec` package is discouraged (see [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec)).

I have searched through the KOMA-Script documentation, but cannot find anything like the `runin` option in `titlesec`. How can I achieve this functionality while using a KOMA-Script class?

Comment: Related: [Indent appears after changing section spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418440/9057)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Older versions of KOMA-Script**

You have to redefine the definition of `\section`, `subsection` *etc*. You use a negativ value to set runin heading, similar to the standard article-class. I have copied the definition of headings from `scrartcl` sometimes in the past. Be aware that this solution may break if `scrartcl`is changed.

If you take a look at page 351 in the English manual for KOMA-Script, you will see that there are several commands for changing the space above and below `chapter`and `part`. Hopefully, we will see a similar command for `\section` and her sisters.

Here, I have redefined both section and subsection to be runin-header.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-1.5ex}%
    {-1em}%{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}% < - negative value here negative value here, 
                             % the values behind % are the original.
                             % no use for rubber values, use a fix value to set the
                             % distance to between heading and the text 
    {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
  }

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{\z@}%
  {-1.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {-1em}%{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}% <- negative value here, the values behind % are the original
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{First section}
     This text follows on the same line as "First section"
\end{document}
```

You use the ordinary `\addtokomafont` etc. to change the font, colour *etc*. And of course, you have to fiddle around with the figures to get the space above you prefer.

**2. Newer versions of KOMA-Script**

I refer to Johannes_B’s answer below.

For the sake of completeness, I will bring your attention to page 363 ff. in the English KOMA-Script manual as of 2015-10-03. The author has (from version 3.16?) added the possibility to interface to `\section{}` and her sisters by the four commands:

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[attributes]{name}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[attributes]{name}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[attributes]{name}
\ProvideSectionCommand[attributes]{name}
```

You may use this commands to define totally new sectioning commands, but also to redefine the existing ones, including the possibility to easily define the `\section{}`-command to be a run-in heading.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
afterskip=-10pt plus -1sp minus 1sp% using rubber is optional 
]{section}
```

Just use a negative value as the first `afterskip` value ( I have used -10pt here).

Comment: It's unfortunate the KOMA classes don't support this directly. However, your answer seems to be the best option for now.

Answer (score 6):

The author of KOMA-Script added an easy to use interface to redeclare sectioning commands (chapters and parts as well). In my opinion, it is much simpler than using `titlesec` ;-)

Of course, you need a fairly recent KOMA-Script-bundle.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-1em,%negative value -> runin
font=\large\normalfont%match the font of your example
]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
This text follows on the same line as "First section"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Level 10 nonsense, a headline you can't distinguish from text. But however, +1 for Johannes_B for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As from `v3.26`, one may also use the switch `runin`.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=on]{section}
```

Comment: Short but almost perfectly good. You only should tell, that in this case the sign of `afterskip` becomes valid for the (horizontal) space after the heading and therefore should also be changed, because the default of `runin` is `bysign`. Compare: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418444/9057 (answer similar question but about how to avoid the run-in of the following paragraph).