# Indent appears after changing section spacing (scrbook, Xetex)

Tags: sectioning, indentation, koma-script

I have a problem in an scrbook document that I could isolate to this element:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=1.5em,
afterskip=3pt
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=1em,
afterskip=3pt
]{subsection,subsubsection}
```

With these lines, the paragraphs after the headings are indented. (Which I'd rather avoid since indents look odd with centered headings.) If I comment out these lines, indents appear as desired.

I assume there is something which I simply don't know about, and adding stuff like "indent=false" to the lists above didn't do anything.

Titlesec is not an option since it conflicts with a KOMA parameter I need.

I am using Xetex and Polyglossia (with bidi) is loaded before these lines, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Use `beforeskip=-1.5em` and `beforeskip=-1em`. The `-` means that the first paragraph after the heading should not be indented.

Comment: Wow, that's quick and easy! Works like a charm - thanks a lot!

Comment: To my shame, after knowing what to look for, I also found it in the scrguide. P. 451 in the English version. (2017-08-08)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Since **KOMA-Script version 3.26** you can also use the new key `afterindent=false`¹ and a positive `beforeskip` to get the desired result.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=1.5em,
  afterskip=3pt
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=1em,
  afterskip=3pt
]{subsection,subsubsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Another Section Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as in the original answer below.

¹Default setting is `afterindent=bysign` which results in the same behavior as in the original answer.

---

**Original answer**

From the KOMA-Script documentation:

> beforeskip (length): The absolute value of the vertical skip before the heading.
>   If the value is negative, then the paragraph indent of the
>   text following the heading is suppressed.

So you have to add a `-` in front of the `beforeskip` values.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1.5em,
  afterskip=3pt
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1em,
  afterskip=3pt
]{subsection,subsubsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Another Section Title}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: If you use a negative value for `afterskip`, you will get a run-in heading.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comment by @esdd:

Use beforeskip=-1.5em and beforeskip=-1em. The - means that the first paragraph after the heading should not be indented.