# Inline subsubsection heading with KOMA

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I want inline subsubsection headings, as displayed in the example below. It is easy to realize them with the titlesec package, but according to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec), there are incompatibilities between KOMA and titlesec.

Is there a solution which does not use titlesec and is fully compatible with the KOMA classes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[.]

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter heading}
\section{A section heading}
\subsection{A subsection heading}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Inline subsubsection heading}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Another inline subsubsection heading}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, there are incompatibilities between `KOMA` and `titlesec`, as written in the manual, but it's basically ignored ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the latest version of KOMA-script, you can declare

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-.5em]{subsubsection}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-.5em]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter heading}
\section{A section heading}
\subsection{A subsection heading}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Inline subsubsection heading.}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Another inline subsubsection heading.}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What does the `style` option do? I couldn't find a more specific description in scrguide and not using it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JuriRobl `style=section` is the default, so you can omit it. I've edited the answer to reflect it.

Comment: The new interface is  quite nice, right? That should have come a lot earlier.

Comment: @Johannes_B Indeed it is. In the manual it is stated that it is a beta feature. Does it mean that we have to expect further improvements?

Comment: As far as i know, Markus is working on this for just a few months, somebody will find a bug. I guess labeling this as *beta* is not a bad idea right now. ;-)

Comment: How can I add the dot automatically? I want to to use `\subsubsection{Test}` but it should print `Test.`