# How to get a section style in KOMA-Script without titlesec package?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

Well, this time I have a very concise doubt about *how to get a section style different from the default one in KOMA-Script* (actually within the `scratcl` class) without use the `titlesec` package.

With the `titlesec` package I can get what I need with this code:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\scshape\bfseries}
{\color{blue} \S \thesubsection .}
{1ex}{\color{blue}}[.\quad]
\subsection{\mbox{}}
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
```

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec) about incompatibilities between `titlesec` and KOMA-Script but I haven't a clear idea yet about how to get the above result in a *barebone* KOMA-Script way.

My MWE of course:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,paper=letter,headings=big,DIV=calc,headsepline=true,titlepage=on,draft=false,index=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table,rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico,es-ucroman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\KOMAoption{parskip}{half*}
\begin{document}

\section{Recuperación de costos}

\subsection{\mbox}

Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the skips before and after the heading. A negative value of `afterskip` will result in a horizontal skip. So you get a runin heading. To change the format of the subsection number in the heading you can redefine `\subsectionformat`. To insert the dot at the end of the subsection title redefine `\sectioncatchphraseformat`.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=-1ex,
  font=\rmfamily\scshape\bfseries\color{blue}
]{subsection}
%
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\S \thesubsection\autodot\hspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
    \hskip #2#3#4%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{.}{}%
  }
```

To ensure that the heading numbers will be controlled by the KOMA-Script class use the `babel` option `es-nosectiondot` and the KOMA-Script option `numbers=enddot`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=14pt,paper=letter,headings=big,DIV=calc,
  headsepline=true,titlepage=on,draft=false,index=totoc,
  parskip=half*,
  numbers=enddot% <- added
]{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% <- added

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table,rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico,es-ucroman,
  es-nosectiondot% <- added
]{babel}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=-1ex,
  font=\rmfamily\scshape\bfseries\color{blue}
]{subsection}
%
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\S \thesubsection\autodot\hspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
    \hskip #2#3#4%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{.}{}%
  }

\begin{document}
\section{Recuperación de costos}

\subsection{\mbox{}}
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text

\subsection{Subsectiontitel}
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```