# Chapter heading KOMA script

Tags: chapters, koma-script, titlesec

I'm using [cleanthesis](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) template and have trouble in to compile since `KOMA-script` and `titlesec` are [not compatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec)

Then, the idea would be to "translate" the titlesec section:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\usekomafont{chapter}}%
{\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad% Line
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}% Chapter number
    }%
}%
{-2.1em}%
{\ctformatchapter}%
[\phantomsection]
```

into a KOMA-script one, that I tried:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
            \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
        {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
            \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \thechapter \autodot\endskip}% Chapter number
        }%
}
```

What I would like is:
[image]

What I have:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I once stood at the exact same point, but I took the other road and switched to `book` class - so I could keep the `titelsec` definitions. I did not regret it in the last two or so years.

Comment: But why are you asking the same question two times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked `cleanthesis` package uses KOMA-Script commands. So it should be used with a KOMA-Script class but it breaks many of their features. For example `listof=totoc` does not work with `cleanthesis`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ctcolorchapternum}{cmyk}{.48, .05, .91, 0}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{ctcolorchapternum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=1sp,
    font=\huge\mdseries
]{chapter}

\renewcommand*\chapterformat{%
    \smash{\textcolor{ctcolorchapterline}{\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{10cm}}}%
    \quad
    \textcolor{ctcolorchapternum}{\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont\thechapter}%
}%

\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax}{\raggedchapter #3}%
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][l]{#2}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\chapter{This is a really long chapter title, so there is a line break}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Or if you use option `b` instead `t` for `\parbox`:

[image]

---

If you *really* want to use `classicthesis` you can add the following code between `\usepackage{classicthesis}` and `\begin{document}` in the file thesis-example.tex of your linked example:

```
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=1sp,
    font=\huge\mdseries
]{chapter}

\renewcommand*\chapterformat{%
    \smash{\textcolor{ctcolorchapterline}{\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{10cm}}}%
    \quad
    \textcolor{ctcolorchapternum}{\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont\thechapter}%
}

\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax}{\raggedchapter #3}%
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][l]{#2}%
}
```

Note that you also can simple remove `chapterprefix=true` from the class options instead using `\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect answer to my question. Thank you so much