# Section Design for Poetry Book

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, koma-script, poetry

After finishing my thesis I am starting to write a book with all my poems.  Due to my thesis I am used to `scrbook` class and can handle `koma script` a bit. But I fail at adjusting the section headings. Consider the following MWE (using LuaLaTeX and depicting a typical verse scheme of mine) using [a design I asked for before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423091/chapter-heading-designs-in-koma-script).:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}     
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{Alegreya}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{themecolor}{RGB}{180, 220, 70}

% Design Chapter
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Huge}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\large\scshape\rmfamily}

\tikzset{
    headings/base/.style = {
        outer sep = 5pt,
        inner sep = 0pt,
        inner xsep = 10pt,
    },
    headings/chapterbackground/.style = {
        headings/base,
        font = \strut,% equal height no matter if capitals or 'g', 'p', etc are used or not
    },
    headings/chapapp/.style = {
        headings/base,
        text = themecolor,
        font = \usekomafont{chapterprefix}
    },
    headings/chapterline/.style = {
        themecolor,
        line width = 2pt,
    }
}

\makeatletter% 
\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(title.base)]
        \node[headings/chapterbackground](title){%
            \parbox[t]
            {\dimexpr\textwidth-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}\relax}%
            {\raggedchapter #3}%
        };
        \node[headings/chapapp,anchor=south east]
        at ([xshift=0pt, yshift=-12pt]title.north east){\ifstr{#2}{}{}{\chapapp}\strut};% Positionierung chapterprefix
        \useasboundingbox
        (current bounding box.north west)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=0pt, yshift=-10pt]current bounding box.south east);%
        \draw[headings/chapterline]
        (current bounding box.south east)++(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)--+(0,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \par
    }{%
        \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}% other section levels using style=chapter
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Poems of Love}
    \addsec{Title of the poem}
    This is the first line\\
    and this the second line of a verse.
    \bigskip

    This is where the common text starts.\\
    \blindtext

    This is a new block without parskip.
    \blindtext
    \bigskip

    \blindtext
    \bigskip

    This is the first line\\
    and the second of the last verse.
\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is:
Chaptertitle instead of chapterprefix
Sectiontitle instead of chaptertitle
Considering the MWE, something like this:

> **Poems of Love (instead of "Chapter", green color)**
>
> **Title of the poem (instead of "Poems of love", black color)**
>
> This is the first line ...

However, I tried to replace "chapter" and "chapterlinesformat" by "section" and "sectionlinesformat", but that does not work and gives error messages. I plan to have the actual chaptertitle on a single page and let the chaptertitle appear again above every section. [I hope this link with an example works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XQqW.jpg)

PS: I am not tied to `scrbook`. I've just chosen it because I know it the most due to my theses. I tried `memoir` class before but was unsatisfied with the layout. So I am open to any suggestions to ease my ideas and appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question or do you really simply want [the solution esdd has shown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423153) but with additional`\renewcommand*{\chapapp}{Poems of love}` and then using `\chapter{Title of the poem}`?

Comment: `memoir` provides for many different layouts. If you didn't like the "out of the box" layout what did you try?