# Biber/Bibtex: One author enumerated

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm checking my university's formatting and they want something that looks like that:

[EVER90a, S. 13-19], [EVER90b, S. 98 f.], [WECK91, S. 110]

I don't have any problems with the style of [WECK91, S. 110], but when it comes to "alphabetically counting" the different pages of one author I find myself trapped.
How can I put this "a, b, …" behind the Year, when I have more than one citation of one book?

Thank you.

Here You can find an MWE:

```
\documentclass[listof=totocnumbered, listof=nochaptergap, bibliography=totocnumbered, parskip, captions=nooneline, fontsize=11pt, twoside=semi, numbers=noenddot, open=right, draft=false, a4paper, footinclude=false, fleqn]{scrreprt}%Dokumentenklasse 
\usepackage[svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Zeichensatzkodierung von 7bit auf 8bit 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Zeichensatzkodierung Unicode bzw. UTF8
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%Silbentrennung nach neuer Rechtschreibung 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{icomma}%Formatiert die Kommas in Matheumgebung ohne Leerzeichen danach
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{tgheros}%macht griechische Großbuchstaben möglich, trotz HELVET-Paket
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.6cm, top=2.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Kopfzeilenformatierung
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, isbn=false, url=false, firstinits=true, maxnames=10]{biblatex} %maxnames ist die Anzahl der Namen, die im Inhaltsverzeichnis angezeigt werden. Darüber hinaus wird mit "u.a." abgekürzt.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}%Tabellen, die über einen Seitenumbruch hinaus gehen ohne abgeschnitten zu werden.
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{placeins}% Package für Floarbarrier um Bilder nicht über Kapitel zu verschieben
\usepackage{titlesec}% Textüberschriften anpassen
\usepackage[bookmarks, raiselinks, pageanchor, hyperindex, colorlinks, citecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, filecolor=black, menucolor=black]{hyperref}


%%% Citation %%%
\newcommand{\zitat}[2][]{\nopagebreak\nolinebreak\mbox{\cite[][#1]{#2}}} 

%%% Literaturverzeichnis %%%
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{\labelelement{\field{citekey}}}% Damit der "citekey" in der Thesis als Zitierungsformatierung verwendet wird


\begin{document}
To make a citation you have to mention an author \zitat{SCHM05}.
But if you have one citation from pages 16 and 17 \zitat[16-17]{MONT09} and another from 20 and 21 \zitat[20-21]{MONT09} the cite key should be changed.
\end{document}
```

This will be the bibliography:

```
    @book{MONT09,
    Author = {Montgomery, Douglas C.},
    Date-Added = {2017-03-15 01:45:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-03-15 04:45:25 +0000},
    Edition = {6},
    Keywords = {SPC, Control chart,},
    Publisher = {John Wiley and Sons, Inc.},
    Title = {Introduction to statistical quality control},
    Year = {2009},
    }

@book{SCHM05,
    Author = {Schmitt, Ingo},
    Date-Added = {2017-03-09 23:26:55 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-03-09 23:29:03 +0000},
    Isbn = {3-486-57907-X},
    Keywords = {{\"A}hnlichkeitsma{\ss}, Distanz, {\"A}hnlichkeit},
    Publisher = {Oldenbourg Wissenschaftsverlag GmbH, M{\"u}nchen},
    Subtitle = {Retrieval, Suchalgorithmen und Anfragebehandlung},
    Title = {{\"A}hnlichkeitssuche in Multimedia-Datenbanken},
    Year = {2005},
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us which citation management package you use at present. You've set both the `bibtex` and the `biber` tags -- the two programs are mutually exclusive. Which program do you use?

Comment: And aplease add a MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. So all of us can test it. I think a,b are for different books of the same year  and the same author...

Comment: Do you mean to suggest that multiple citations of the same bibentry should be distinguished through the addition of a(n) `a`, `b`, etc.? That seems absolutely ludicrous and pointless, and, more worryingly, liable to be confusing to the readers. Are you sure they don't mean you add those when the same author(s) published more than one work in the same year?  (I would ask the administrators/powers-that-be to confirm that they do not understand how bibliographies are supposed to work before trying to implement this.)

Comment: I'm with @jon. Aside from anything else, what should you do if you have two entries for the same author and year? Since alphabetical suffixes are the standard way to distinguish these, what do they think you should do in this case?

Comment: Don't load `helvet` if you are loading `tgheros`. It is completely pointless. Are you really using Computer Modern Roman serif with TG Heros for sans? That is pretty horrible.

Comment: Please check if it really is the requirement to use the additional letter as soon as the page numbers in the citation are different. Do you then want all citations (of the same work) in the bibliography, i.e. if 'Smith09a' and 'Smith09b' refer to pages 10-20 and 30-40 of the same book, respectively, do both go into the bibliography? What if you cite 'Smith09, pp. 10-20' twice, does it get the same letter?

Comment: BTW: Your preamble loads a lot of packages. cfr already mentions some questionable font combinations. But you also load `titlesec` with a Koma class [which isn't a good idea](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/35864).  `fancyhdr` is also not recommended with Koma classes. `\newcommand{\zitat}[2][]{\nopagebreak\nolinebreak\mbox{\cite[][#1]{#2}}} ` seems a bit odd, `biblatex` is reluctant to break citations, but it does so when necessary, I don't think working against that radically is a good idea. Finally, `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{\labelelement{\field{citekey}}}` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Hello guys:
@moewe: if I don't use "declareLableAlphaTemplate" it will just write the first letter capital, not all 4 of them. Also when I have an ISO, the University wants just the 3 letters e.g. [ISO02]. It was the only way I saw to archive that.
The other one with the forcing I deleted.
Also I want the book just once in the biblipgraphy not twice or more. Also the letter would be the same if the pages are the same.
And to all: the university said: small letter, if there is more than one citation of the same year.

Comment: The bad thing is, it's not specified if that means if one author has two books of the same year, or if I cite several chapters from one book (which would be the same year as well). But I think the easiest thing is to ignore that.

And I will read the packages of helvet and tgheros and the titlesec to make sure I just load what I need. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm actually quite confident that they want you to add a letter only if you have two or more different entries from the same year, not if you cite several pages. It would just make no sense at all to add letters in the latter case. If you set up `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` differently, you will not have to resort to using the `citekey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I think we established that the rule 'use a different letter for different pages' stems from a misinterpretation of the rules that actually call for a disambiguation letter in case there are two entries by the same author from the same year.

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{\labelelement{\field{citekey}}}
```

Is a very ad-hoc way to achieve this the desired label format.

Use

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
      \field{label}
      \field[strwidth=4, strside=left, uppercase=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
```

with `maxalphanes=1` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, isbn=false, url=false, firstinits=true, maxnames=10, maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}  
@book{MONT09,
  Author = {Montgomery, Douglas C.},
  Edition = {6},
  Keywords = {SPC, Control chart,},
  Publisher = {John Wiley and Sons, Inc.},
  Title = {Introduction to statistical quality control},
  Year = {2009},
}

@book{SCHM05,
  Author = {Schmitt, Ingo},
  Isbn = {3-486-57907-X},
  Keywords = {{\"A}hnlichkeitsma{\ss}, Distanz, {\"A}hnlichkeit},
  Publisher = {Oldenbourg Wissenschaftsverlag GmbH, M{\"u}nchen},
  Subtitle = {Retrieval, Suchalgorithmen und Anfragebehandlung},
  Title = {{\"A}hnlichkeitssuche in Multimedia-Datenbanken},
  Year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}  
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
      \field{label}
      \field[strwidth=4, strside=left, uppercase=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{document}
To make a citation you have to mention an author \cite{SCHM05}.
\cite[16-17]{MONT09}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives then

> [MONT09], [SCHM05]

Comment: Wow! That's great. Thank you so much. That solved the problem with the letter.

Comment: What it didn't solve or what it made worse is the above mentioned with the norms: Also when I have an ISO, the University wants just the 3 letters e.g. [ISO02].
In the bibliography has to be "Norm ISO 12220 (January 2002): Norm about whatever" and in the text has to be [ISO02]
Any ideas about that?

Comment: @Yannic Add `label = {ISO}` to the entry. That overrides the `author`

Comment: Thanks, I now added the Bibtex label "Label" and added the cite key how I wanted it to look =)