# Replacing titlesec and customizing headings (part and chapter number in the middle of a string)

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec, chinese

I used `titlesec` to define the chapter headings for a Chinese book. However, as of texlive 2020 there are incompatibilities with Koma Script and `titlesec` (in my specific setting, I cannot produce a minimal example showing the conflict). I want to get rid of `titlesec` but I do not know how to reach the effects. What I am looking for is something to put the section number in the middle of the heading: "The 5th section".

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\center\Large\bfseries}{Chapter\thechapter{}Number}{20pt}{}  
\titleformat{\appendix}[block]{\center\Large\bfseries}{\appendixname}{20pt}{}  
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{10pt}{}  
\titleformat{\tableofcontents}[block]{\center\Large\bfseries}{Some special string}{20pt}{}  
\titleformat{\part}[block]{\center\Large\bfseries}{Part \thepart{} Number}{20pt}{}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\part{A part}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{foo}

\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec?rq=1

Comment: Yes, thanks! I saw this before, but these seem to be solutions to other problems. I need the section number in the middle of a string. Like "The 5th Section".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand what `\titleformat{\appendix}` and `\titleformat{\tableofcontents}` should do: neither `\appendix` nor `\tableofcontents` is a sectioning command.

Your `\titleformat` macros for `\part`, `\chapter` and `\section` can be replaced by

```latex
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{Part \thepart{} Number\hspace{20pt}}
\renewcommand*{\partheadmidvskip}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chapapp \thechapter Number\hspace{20pt}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\hspace{10pt}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\Large}
\setkomafont{part}{\Large}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\setkomafont{section}{\large}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{Part \thepart{} Number\hspace{20pt}}
\renewcommand*{\partheadmidvskip}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chapapp \thechapter Number\hspace{20pt}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\hspace{10pt}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\Large}
\setkomafont{part}{\Large}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\setkomafont{section}{\large}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{A part}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{foo}
\section{bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the appendix and toc. They can be set with renewcaptionname. This almost solves the problem, but the appendix shall have a heading like "附录 A ~~~ 练习题答案". With the current settings it comes out as "附录 A 练习题答案", that is there is no space after the "A".

Comment: Found a solution for the appendix. This was in the `langsci` class already. `\appto\appendix{
% format of the appendix title page
 \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{
  \mbox{\chapapp~\thechapter\hspace{20pt}}
 }
% format of the TOC entry
 \renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{
  \ifstr{#1}{}{
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}
  }{
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\chapapp~#1 #2}
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following definition with `\phantom....`

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{titlesec}
% Incorrect ToC link to \addsec
% \titleformat{\section}{\Huge\sffamily}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
% Correct ToC link to \addsec
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\sffamily}{\thesection}{0.5em}{\phantomsection}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage

    \section{foo}

    \clearpage

    \addsec{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using titlesec in your answer? The OP probably wants to get rid of it, because it is incompatible with KOMA and warnings are thrown. And why do you change the document class?

Comment: You seem to be answering another question.

Comment: may I suggest you write out your own answers so we can learn from you how it is to be done --

Comment: My computer is broken, i cannot, sorry.