# Formatting Issue with scrheadings - Inner Head appears as "Chapter 0"

Tags: formatting, header-footer, emptypage

Unfortunately I am confronted with an issue I don't know how to solve in a timely manner. My recent research in the internet was equally unsuccessful. Thats why I ask you for help and I hope there is somebody skilled out there who may have the time to resolve this issue with/for me.

Back to the topic: When typesetting there are **tree different minor problems** that always occur. Two of them can be descibed as "wrong inner heads". More specifically: Chapter 0 is printed although it should be the name of the chapter as in the other ToCs... Table of Content (*Page 1*), Table of Figures (*Page 9*) and Table of Tables (*Page 11*) works perfectly as intended! Only the two other Tables (*Page 3-8*) are faulty. In order to illustrate this issue to you in a quick and simple way there are two images attached. The red comments are describing what's going on. The third issue concerns additional blank pages (*page 7 + page 8*). Because of the fact that page 7 is an "odd-page", the Table of Figures (*page 9*) actually has to be exactly there, starting on (*page 7*). I cannot understand why LaTeX inserts two blank pages here.

Thank you very much for you patience and help! The MWE is att

Kind regards,
Max

[image]

[image]

- 
- 

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=12mm, 12pt]{scrbook}

% PREAMBLE
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\setstretch{1,25}

\usepackage[
top=2.0cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
headheight=0.75cm,
headsep=1cm,
width=155mm
]{geometry}
\geometry{
bindingoffset=14mm,
includehead=true,
includefoot=false, 
%marginparsep=0.25cm,
%marginparwidth=1.5cm,
%showframe
}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[chapter]{chapter}                     
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\lehead{Seite~\pagemark}                                
\rohead{Seite~\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\setheadsepline{0.2pt}                              
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize\rmfamily}        
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}          
\usepackage{tocloft}                            
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}                  
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}                      
\renewcommand*{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}             
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}         

% Notation Style
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,acronym,sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossary-super}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis} %create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}
\glsdisablehyper
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
        \begin{longtable}{lp{0.585\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
        \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Beschreibung & \bfseries Einheit \\
        \hline \vspace{2pt}
        \endhead}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
        & $\glsunit{##1}$  \tabularnewline
    }
}


% Abkürzungen Style
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\newlength\acrwidth
\appto\newacronymhook{%
  \settowidth{\acrwidth}{\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}}%
  \addtolength{\acrwidth}{0.5em}%
  \ifdim\acrwidth>\glstreeindent
    \setlength{\glstreeindent}{\acrwidth}%
  \fi
}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \columnsep5em
  \setglossarystyle{mcoltree}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent\glstreeindent\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \makebox[\glstreeindent][l]{%
       \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

% Abkürzungen - Beispiele!
\newacronym{DLR}{DLR}{Deutsches Zentrum für Luft- und Raumfahrt}
\newacronym{AHS}{AHS}{American Helicopter Society}
\newacronym{JAHS}{JAHS}{Journal of the AHS}
\newacronym{MR}{MR}{Main Rotor}
\newacronym{}{}{MTOW aximum Take Oﬀ Weight}
\newacronym{TR}{TR}{Tail Rotor}
\newacronym{IGE}{IGE}{im Bodeneﬀekt}
\newacronym{ICAO}{ICAO}{International Civil Aviation Organization}
\newacronym{HS}{HS}{Horizontal Stabilizer}
\newacronym{ECD}{ECD}{Eurocopter Deutschland}
\newacronym{agl}{agl}{above ground level}
\newacronym{VNE}{VNE}{never-exceed velocity}
\newacronym{MBB}{MBB}{Messerschmit–Bolkow–Blohm}
\newacronym{PSD}{PSD}{power spectral density}
\newacronym{SA}{SA}{situation awareness}
\newacronym{IK}{IK}{Inverse Kinematik}
\newacronym{RPY}{RPY}{Roll-Pitch-Yaw}
\newacronym{DH}{DH}{Denavit-Hartenberg}
\newacronym{MATLAB}{MATLAB}{MATrix LABoratory}
\newacronym{K-Raum}{K-Raum}{Konfigurationsraum}
\newacronym{OBB}{OBB}{Oriented Bounding Box}
\newacronym{V-Clip}{V-Clip}{Voronoi-Clip}
\newacronym{GJK}{GJK}{Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi}
\newacronym{H-Walk}{H-Walk}{Hierarchical Walk}
\newacronym{MEX}{MEX}{MATLAB Executable}
\newacronym{CAD}{CAD}{Computer-Aided Design}
\newacronym{SPS}{SPS}{Speicherprogrammierbare Steuerung}
\newacronym{CLIK}{CLIK}{Closed-Loop Inverse Kinematic}
\newacronym{RAM}{RAM}{Random-Access Memory}
\newacronym{ST}{ST}{Structured Text}
\newacronym{ST3}{ST3}{Structured Text3}
\newacronym{ST4}{ST4}{Structured Text4}
\newacronym{ST5}{ST5}{Structured Text5}
\newacronym{ST6}{ST6}{Structured Text6}
\newacronym{ST7}{ST7}{Structured Text7}
\newacronym{ST8}{ST8}{Structured Text8}
\newacronym{ST9}{ST9}{Structured Text9}


% Formelzeichen - Beispiele!
\newglossaryentry{Position}{name=${P=\left[P_x, P_y, P_z\right]^T}$,
    description={Positionsvektor in x-, y- und z-Richtung},
    unit={\si{\meter}}}

\newglossaryentry{Orientierung}{name=${R=\left[R_x, R_y, R_z\right]^T}$,
    description={Rotationsvektor um die $x$-, $y$- und $z$-Achse},
    unit={rad}}

\newglossaryentry{Geschwindigkeit}{name=$v$,
    description={Geschwindigkeitsvektor},
    unit={\si{\metre\per\second}}}

\newglossaryentry{Koordinatensystem}{name=$K_i$,
    description={Mit $i$ gekennzeichnete Koordinatensystem},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Rotationsmatrix}{name=$_i^jA$,
    description={Rotationsmatrix, vom Koordinatensystem $K_i$ zum Koordinatensystem $K_j$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Transformationsmatrix}{name=${_i^jT}$,
    description={Tranformationsmatrix, vom Koordinatensystem $K_i$ zum Koordinatensystem $K_j$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Euler-Winkel}{name=${\alpha, \beta, \gamma}$,
    description={Euler-Winkel zur Roation um die ZYX-Achsen eines Koordinatensystems},
    unit={rad}}

\newglossaryentry{Kalkulationszeit}{name=$t_{calc}$,
    description={Kalkulationszeit},
    unit={\si{\second}}}

\newglossaryentry{Bewegungsgeschwindigkeit}{name=$\dot{q}$,
    description={Bewegungsgeschwindigkeit der Antriebe eines Robotersystems},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Jacobi-Matrix}{name=$J\left(q\right)$,
    description={Jacobi-Matrix für die Roboterstellung $q$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Pseudoinverse}{name=$J^+\left(q\right)$,
    description={Pseudoinverse Jacobi-Matrix für die Roboterstellung $q$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Konfigurationsraum}{name=$C$,
    description={Konfigurationsraum eines Roboters},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Arbeitsbereich}{name=$\mathcal{W}$,
    description={Arbeitsbereich eines Roboters},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{DH-Parameter}{name=${a_i, d_i, \alpha_i, \Theta_i}$,
    description={DH-Parameter des Koordinatensystems $K_i$ zu seinem Referenzkoordinatensystem $K_{i-1}$},
    unit={-}}


\newglossaryentry{Voronoi-Region}{name=$\mathcal{VR}\left(X\right)$,
    description={Voronoi-Region eines Elements $X$},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Voronoi-Ebene}{name=$\mathcal{VP}\left({X,Y}\right)$,
    description={Grenze zwischen den Voronoi-Regionen der Elemente $X$ und $Y$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Konvexes Objekt}{name=$P_i$,
    description={Konvexes 2- oder 3-dimensionales Objekt mit dem Index $i$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Feature}{name=${X, Y}$,
    description={Features beschreiben Ecken, Kanten oder Flächen eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Nachbar}{name=$N$,
    description={Nachbar eines betrachteten Features},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{clostestPoints}{name=${x, y}$,
    description={Nächstgelegenen Punkte eines Featurepaars $X$, $Y$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Vertex}{name=$V$,
    description={Vertexpunkt eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Edge}{name=$E$,
    description={Kante eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Face}{name=$F$,
    description={Fläche eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{MinkowskiSum}{name=$A \oplus B$,
    description={Minkowski Summe der Punktmengen $A$ und $B$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{MinkowskiDiff}{name=$A \ominus B$,
    description={Minkowski Differenz der Punktmengen $A$ und $B$},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Simplex}{name=$coV$,
    description={Simplex},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Supportmapping}{name=$s_P$,
    description={Supportmapping des konvexen Objekts $P$},
    unit={-}}


\newglossaryentry{Liniensegment}{name=$S$,
    description={Liniensegment},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Gelenkwinkel}{name=$\Theta_i$,
    description={Winkel des $i$-ten Gelenks des UR10},
    unit={rad}}

\newglossaryentry{Stuetzpunkt}{name=$sp_i$,
    description={Stützpunkt, zur Beschreibung des Robotersystems durch Primitive},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Einheitsnormalenvektor}{name=$n$,
    description={Einheitsnormalenvektor einer Ebene},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Distanz}{name=$d_{ij}$,
    description={Distanz zwischen einem Kollisionspaar $ij$},
    unit={\si{\metre}},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Sicherheitsabstand}{name=$d_{safety}$,
    description={Vom Kollisionssystem einzuhaltender Sicherheitsabstand},
    unit={\si{\metre}}}

\newglossaryentry{Zielfunktion}{name=$H_{ij}\left(q\right)$,
    description={Zielfunktionswert für das Kollisionspaar $ij$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Gesamtzielfunktion}{name=$H_{ges}\left(q\right)$,
    description={Zielfunktionswert des gesamten Kollisionssystems},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Schrittweite}{name=$h$,
    description={Schrittweite des Gradienten},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Nullraumbewegung}{name=$\dot{q}_N$,
    description={Nullraumbewegung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{GradientZielfunktion}{name=${\Delta H_{ges}, \Delta H_{i,ges}}$,
    description={Gradient der Gesamtzielfunktion (des $i$-ten Antriebs) des Robotersystems},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Verstaerkungsfaktor}{name=$\alpha$,
    description={Verstärkungsfaktor der Nullraumbewegung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Spline}{name=$c \left(t\right)$,
    description={kubisch hermetischer Spline},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Splineparameter}{name=${P_s, P_e, m_s, m_e}$,
    description={Wert und Steigung des Startpunkts $_s$ und Endpunkts $_e$ zur Splineberechnung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Kontrollintervall}{name=$k$,
    description={Intervall, indem die Kollisionserkennung durchgeführt wird},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{idxBewegungssteuerung}{name=$n$,
    description={Iterator der Bewegungssteuerung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Mittelwert}{name=$\overline{t}_{calc,d}$,
    description={Arithmetisches Mittel der Kalkulationszeit eines Distanzberechnungsverfahrens $d$},
    unit={\si{\second}}}

\newglossaryentry{StandardAbweichung}{name=$\sigma_{calc,d}$,
    description={Standardabweichung der Kalkulationszeit eines Distanzberechnungsverfahrens $d$},
    unit={\si{\second}}} % Referenz in TeX später | Table darstellung | description
    
\makeglossaries

% Chapter Style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\filleft\huge\bfseries}
        {\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\raisebox{120pt}[135pt][0pt]{{\usefont{T1}{lmss}{b}{n}\fontsize{80pt}{95pt}\selectfont\thechapter}}}
        {}  
        }   
        {-14ex} 
        {}  
        [\vspace{1.5ex}\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\chapter}
             {0pc}{*30}{*5}[0pc]
\renewcommand\chapterformat{{\fontsize{80pt}{80pt}\selectfont}{\thechapter}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\vspace*{-1ex}}{}% 
  #2#3%
  \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}%
  \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par\nobreakd
}%

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

% ToC
\mainmatter
\tocloftpagestyle{scrheadings}                                              

\ihead{Inhaltsverzeichnis}                  
\tableofcontents                                    
\rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}                       
\lohead{\headmark}
\cleardoublepage

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.82\linewidth}
    \printglossary[
    type=\acronymtype,  
    nonumberlist,               
    title=Abkürzungen,
%   toctitle=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
    style=mystyle
    ]
\endgroup

\cleardoublepage

\begingroup
    \ihead{Notationen}
    \printglossary[
    nonumberlist,
    title=Notationen,
%   toctitle=Notationsverzeichnis,
    style=symbunitlong
    ]
    \glsaddall
\endgroup

\begingroup
    \chapter*{\label{figure_index}Abbildungen}
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\rmfamily Abbildungsverzeichnis}
    \ihead{Abbildungen}
    %\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
    \listoffigures
    \cleardoublepage
\endgroup

\begingroup
    \chapter*{\label{table_index}Tabellen}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\rmfamily Tabellenverzeichnis}
    \ihead{Tabellen}
    %\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
    \listoftables
    \cleardoublepage
\endgroup

% Thesis
\chapter{Beispielkapitel}

\blindtext[17]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // As a general hint Latex needs several compiles to get such numbers right. This is because it first collects all such references, and in a second run it updates them. So, if you are lucky, all you may need may be a second or third compile run, without introducing changes.

Comment: you shouldn't use titlesec/titletoc in a KOMA class.

Comment: @Ulrike Fische; May you please tell me why and do you have an idea how to replace it in my particular case? Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, please in the future include a **minimal** working example (MWE), your code is 413 lines long which is not a minimal example, in the glossaries package there are example-glossaries that you can use instead of including actual entries. Please consult [this guideline in the future](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) as it will help us help you.

Your issue that I could find was you were putting your notation into `\begingroup`'s which seemed to be causing issues (notwithstanding other issues Ulrike has commented you with). The reason why "Abkürzungen" was not appearing is because `\ihead{Abkürzungen}` was not included in that section. This is your code with the required edits:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=12mm, 12pt]{scrbook}

% PREAMBLE
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\setstretch{1,25}

\usepackage[
top=2.0cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
headheight=0.75cm,
headsep=1cm,
width=155mm
]{geometry}
\geometry{
bindingoffset=14mm,
includehead=true,
includefoot=false, 
%marginparsep=0.25cm,
%marginparwidth=1.5cm,
%showframe
}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[chapter]{chapter}                     
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\lehead{Seite~\pagemark}                                
\rohead{Seite~\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\setheadsepline{0.2pt}                              
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize\rmfamily}        
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}          
\usepackage{tocloft}                            
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}                  
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}                      
\renewcommand*{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}             
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}         

% Notation Style
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,acronym,sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossary-super}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis} %create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}
\glsdisablehyper
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
        \begin{longtable}{lp{0.585\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
        \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Beschreibung & \bfseries Einheit \\
        \hline \vspace{2pt}
        \endhead}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
        & $\glsunit{##1}$  \tabularnewline
    }
}


% Abkürzungen Style
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\newlength\acrwidth
\appto\newacronymhook{%
  \settowidth{\acrwidth}{\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}}%
  \addtolength{\acrwidth}{0.5em}%
  \ifdim\acrwidth>\glstreeindent
    \setlength{\glstreeindent}{\acrwidth}%
  \fi
}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \columnsep5em
  \setglossarystyle{mcoltree}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent\glstreeindent\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \makebox[\glstreeindent][l]{%
       \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

% Abkürzungen - Beispiele!
\newacronym{DLR}{DLR}{Deutsches Zentrum für Luft- und Raumfahrt}
\newacronym{AHS}{AHS}{American Helicopter Society}
\newacronym{JAHS}{JAHS}{Journal of the AHS}
\newacronym{MR}{MR}{Main Rotor}
\newacronym{}{}{MTOW aximum Take Oﬀ Weight}
\newacronym{TR}{TR}{Tail Rotor}
\newacronym{IGE}{IGE}{im Bodeneﬀekt}
\newacronym{ICAO}{ICAO}{International Civil Aviation Organization}
\newacronym{HS}{HS}{Horizontal Stabilizer}
\newacronym{ECD}{ECD}{Eurocopter Deutschland}
\newacronym{agl}{agl}{above ground level}
\newacronym{VNE}{VNE}{never-exceed velocity}
\newacronym{MBB}{MBB}{Messerschmit–Bolkow–Blohm}
\newacronym{PSD}{PSD}{power spectral density}
\newacronym{SA}{SA}{situation awareness}
\newacronym{IK}{IK}{Inverse Kinematik}
\newacronym{RPY}{RPY}{Roll-Pitch-Yaw}
\newacronym{DH}{DH}{Denavit-Hartenberg}
\newacronym{MATLAB}{MATLAB}{MATrix LABoratory}
\newacronym{K-Raum}{K-Raum}{Konfigurationsraum}
\newacronym{OBB}{OBB}{Oriented Bounding Box}
\newacronym{V-Clip}{V-Clip}{Voronoi-Clip}
\newacronym{GJK}{GJK}{Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi}
\newacronym{H-Walk}{H-Walk}{Hierarchical Walk}
\newacronym{MEX}{MEX}{MATLAB Executable}
\newacronym{CAD}{CAD}{Computer-Aided Design}
\newacronym{SPS}{SPS}{Speicherprogrammierbare Steuerung}
\newacronym{CLIK}{CLIK}{Closed-Loop Inverse Kinematic}
\newacronym{RAM}{RAM}{Random-Access Memory}
\newacronym{ST}{ST}{Structured Text}
\newacronym{ST3}{ST3}{Structured Text3}
\newacronym{ST4}{ST4}{Structured Text4}
\newacronym{ST5}{ST5}{Structured Text5}
\newacronym{ST6}{ST6}{Structured Text6}
\newacronym{ST7}{ST7}{Structured Text7}
\newacronym{ST8}{ST8}{Structured Text8}
\newacronym{ST9}{ST9}{Structured Text9}


% Formelzeichen - Beispiele!
\newglossaryentry{Position}{name=${P=\left[P_x, P_y, P_z\right]^T}$,
    description={Positionsvektor in x-, y- und z-Richtung},
    unit={\si{\meter}}}

\newglossaryentry{Orientierung}{name=${R=\left[R_x, R_y, R_z\right]^T}$,
    description={Rotationsvektor um die $x$-, $y$- und $z$-Achse},
    unit={rad}}

\newglossaryentry{Geschwindigkeit}{name=$v$,
    description={Geschwindigkeitsvektor},
    unit={\si{\metre\per\second}}}

\newglossaryentry{Koordinatensystem}{name=$K_i$,
    description={Mit $i$ gekennzeichnete Koordinatensystem},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Rotationsmatrix}{name=$_i^jA$,
    description={Rotationsmatrix, vom Koordinatensystem $K_i$ zum Koordinatensystem $K_j$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Transformationsmatrix}{name=${_i^jT}$,
    description={Tranformationsmatrix, vom Koordinatensystem $K_i$ zum Koordinatensystem $K_j$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Euler-Winkel}{name=${\alpha, \beta, \gamma}$,
    description={Euler-Winkel zur Roation um die ZYX-Achsen eines Koordinatensystems},
    unit={rad}}

\newglossaryentry{Kalkulationszeit}{name=$t_{calc}$,
    description={Kalkulationszeit},
    unit={\si{\second}}}

\newglossaryentry{Bewegungsgeschwindigkeit}{name=$\dot{q}$,
    description={Bewegungsgeschwindigkeit der Antriebe eines Robotersystems},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Jacobi-Matrix}{name=$J\left(q\right)$,
    description={Jacobi-Matrix für die Roboterstellung $q$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Pseudoinverse}{name=$J^+\left(q\right)$,
    description={Pseudoinverse Jacobi-Matrix für die Roboterstellung $q$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Konfigurationsraum}{name=$C$,
    description={Konfigurationsraum eines Roboters},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Arbeitsbereich}{name=$\mathcal{W}$,
    description={Arbeitsbereich eines Roboters},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{DH-Parameter}{name=${a_i, d_i, \alpha_i, \Theta_i}$,
    description={DH-Parameter des Koordinatensystems $K_i$ zu seinem Referenzkoordinatensystem $K_{i-1}$},
    unit={-}}


\newglossaryentry{Voronoi-Region}{name=$\mathcal{VR}\left(X\right)$,
    description={Voronoi-Region eines Elements $X$},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Voronoi-Ebene}{name=$\mathcal{VP}\left({X,Y}\right)$,
    description={Grenze zwischen den Voronoi-Regionen der Elemente $X$ und $Y$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Konvexes Objekt}{name=$P_i$,
    description={Konvexes 2- oder 3-dimensionales Objekt mit dem Index $i$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Feature}{name=${X, Y}$,
    description={Features beschreiben Ecken, Kanten oder Flächen eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Nachbar}{name=$N$,
    description={Nachbar eines betrachteten Features},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{clostestPoints}{name=${x, y}$,
    description={Nächstgelegenen Punkte eines Featurepaars $X$, $Y$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Vertex}{name=$V$,
    description={Vertexpunkt eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Edge}{name=$E$,
    description={Kante eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Face}{name=$F$,
    description={Fläche eines konvexen Objekts},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{MinkowskiSum}{name=$A \oplus B$,
    description={Minkowski Summe der Punktmengen $A$ und $B$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{MinkowskiDiff}{name=$A \ominus B$,
    description={Minkowski Differenz der Punktmengen $A$ und $B$},
    unit={-},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Simplex}{name=$coV$,
    description={Simplex},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Supportmapping}{name=$s_P$,
    description={Supportmapping des konvexen Objekts $P$},
    unit={-}}


\newglossaryentry{Liniensegment}{name=$S$,
    description={Liniensegment},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Gelenkwinkel}{name=$\Theta_i$,
    description={Winkel des $i$-ten Gelenks des UR10},
    unit={rad}}

\newglossaryentry{Stuetzpunkt}{name=$sp_i$,
    description={Stützpunkt, zur Beschreibung des Robotersystems durch Primitive},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Einheitsnormalenvektor}{name=$n$,
    description={Einheitsnormalenvektor einer Ebene},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Distanz}{name=$d_{ij}$,
    description={Distanz zwischen einem Kollisionspaar $ij$},
    unit={\si{\metre}},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{Sicherheitsabstand}{name=$d_{safety}$,
    description={Vom Kollisionssystem einzuhaltender Sicherheitsabstand},
    unit={\si{\metre}}}

\newglossaryentry{Zielfunktion}{name=$H_{ij}\left(q\right)$,
    description={Zielfunktionswert für das Kollisionspaar $ij$},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Gesamtzielfunktion}{name=$H_{ges}\left(q\right)$,
    description={Zielfunktionswert des gesamten Kollisionssystems},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Schrittweite}{name=$h$,
    description={Schrittweite des Gradienten},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Nullraumbewegung}{name=$\dot{q}_N$,
    description={Nullraumbewegung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{GradientZielfunktion}{name=${\Delta H_{ges}, \Delta H_{i,ges}}$,
    description={Gradient der Gesamtzielfunktion (des $i$-ten Antriebs) des Robotersystems},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Verstaerkungsfaktor}{name=$\alpha$,
    description={Verstärkungsfaktor der Nullraumbewegung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Spline}{name=$c \left(t\right)$,
    description={kubisch hermetischer Spline},
    unit={-}}

%\newglossaryentry{Splineparameter}{name=${P_s, P_e, m_s, m_e}$,
%    description={Wert und Steigung des Startpunkts $_s$ und Endpunkts $_e$ zur Splineberechnung},
%    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Kontrollintervall}{name=$k$,
    description={Intervall, indem die Kollisionserkennung durchgeführt wird},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{idxBewegungssteuerung}{name=$n$,
    description={Iterator der Bewegungssteuerung},
    unit={-}}

\newglossaryentry{Mittelwert}{name=$\overline{t}_{calc,d}$,
    description={Arithmetisches Mittel der Kalkulationszeit eines Distanzberechnungsverfahrens $d$},
    unit={\si{\second}}}

\newglossaryentry{StandardAbweichung}{name=$\sigma_{calc,d}$,
    description={Standardabweichung der Kalkulationszeit eines Distanzberechnungsverfahrens $d$},
    unit={\si{\second}}} % Referenz in TeX später | Table darstellung | description
    
\makeglossaries

% Chapter Style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\filleft\huge\bfseries}
        {\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\raisebox{120pt}[135pt][0pt]{{\usefont{T1}{lmss}{b}{n}\fontsize{80pt}{95pt}\selectfont\thechapter}}}
        {}  
        }   
        {-14ex} 
        {}  
        [\vspace{1.5ex}\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\chapter}
             {0pc}{*30}{*5}[0pc]
\renewcommand\chapterformat{{\fontsize{80pt}{80pt}\selectfont}{\thechapter}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\vspace*{-1ex}}{}% 
  #2#3%
  \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}%
  \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par\nobreakd
}%

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

% ToC
\mainmatter
\tocloftpagestyle{scrheadings}                                              

\ihead{Inhaltsverzeichnis}                  
\tableofcontents                                    
\rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}                       
\lohead{\headmark}
\cleardoublepage

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis

    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \ihead{Abkürzungen}
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.82\linewidth}
    \printglossary[
    type=\acronymtype,  
    nonumberlist,               
    title=Abkürzungen,
%   toctitle=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
    style=mystyle
    ]

\cleardoublepage


    \ihead{Notationen}
    \printglossary[
    nonumberlist,
    title=Notationen,
%   toctitle=Notationsverzeichnis,
    style=symbunitlong
    ]
    \glsaddall



    \chapter*{\label{figure_index}Abbildungen}
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\rmfamily Abbildungsverzeichnis}
    \ihead{Abbildungen}
    %\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
    \listoffigures
    \cleardoublepage



    \chapter*{\label{table_index}Tabellen}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\rmfamily Tabellenverzeichnis}
    \ihead{Tabellen}
    %\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
    \listoftables
    \cleardoublepage


% Thesis
\chapter{Beispielkapitel}

\blindtext[17]

\end{document}
```

It produces this output as required:

[image: Abk]

This in the notation:

[image: notation showing]

The reason why there is a clear page is you have 1 too many notation entries which means the notation is continuing onto the following page, you will have to ask a new question about how to force it to fit onto the space you have as I am not sure what to do. I commented out one notation entry and it produced this:

[image: showing one less entry]

Please seek help from another question about how to either change the space of your title for this one section to force it to fit or otherwise. If my answer or another answer has answered your question then please consider ticking the answer on the left hand side. Hope this helps.

Comment: First; thank you so much for you quick respond and you overall effort. This is unbelievable outstanding performance! Thanks as well for your suggestions concerning the MWE! I keep that in mind! All in all the problem is gone for now. 

May you please tell me what you mean with your very last comment? -How to either change the space of your title for this one section to force it to fit or otherwise? Thank you very much @ LaccaseTVersicolor!

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer (or a different answer, or any answer on your previous questions) has helped with your problem, please "accept it" so that the question is closed, if you go to the top of the answer there is a tick mark, click it only if you are happy as it is good etiquette for the site and means the question won't get bumped in 6 months :) I will edit my question now with a work around for you, just give me a few minutes or so and I will answer your second question, thank you for the kind words :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just accepted your answer by clicking the tick mark. In addition to that; do you know what Ulrike Fischer is talking about when saying I shouldn't use titlesec/titletoc in a KOMA class? Would be also very happy if you may shortly get back to me concerning this topic. 

Kind regards from germany!
Max

Comment: @MaximilianP could you just confirm, is this your final notation list? Will you be adding anymore whatsoever? There is an easy solution but it depends upon if you will be adding more!

Comment: I will indeed add some more abbreviations later on... very likely...

Comment: Then do not worry, it was only if that was final that you would need to be concerned about it creating the undesirable "newpage" - if you are adding more then it will naturally spill over into the new page! I am not sure about the titlesec/toc incompatibilities but I found this link which describes them (in German funnily enough) so have a look if you can, your code seems to be fine though when using hyperref so I don't think you should be worried:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec#36310

Comment: I think I didn't get you right.  I think your last comment is about the "List of abbreviations". Did I get you right? What do you mean with "concerned about it creating the undesirable newpage" and what did you mean with "Please seek help from another question about how to either change the space of your title for this one section to force it to fit or otherwise."?

Please let me know if you change the code again. 

Sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: I was referring to the "List of Notation" you have called "Notationnen", that is the one I mean are you going to add more notation entries to, that is the one causing the extra page from your original question (on the image in your question "this has to be cleared as well" page, they are the undesirable newpages). 

If you are adding more notation then don't worry as the notation will continue onto the next page (the empty pages you do not want) but if you are not adding more notations then let me know and I will edit my answer to squeeze it onto one page, I hope I have explained properly :)

Comment: Yeah, got it! :)