# Styling an "article" document

Tags: article, options

I'm writing a document using the class *article*. There are some things I'd like to change, for example:

- Always center `\section` and `\subsection` titles without doing it manually each time using `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`
- decrease the spacing between list elements without writing `\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-1mm]` each time.
- etc.

Where can I find instructions about this? I couldn't find a "manual" where I could look up all of the options and keys. In case there is not a manual, how could I achieve these results?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no comprehensive manual. The best approximation for a "do-it-all" is the documentation of `memoir`; indeed you *can* use `memoir` for an article. Simple changes to the section headings can be done with `sectsty`; more complex are done with `titlesec`. For lists the reference is `enumitem` (which you're already using). You might consult the ["Breve guida"](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/egtex.html) where some frequently used packages are described (in Italian).

Comment: @egreg I've seen some quesitons about `titlesec`, it looks kind of complicated but I guess I'll have to look into it deeper now... :)

Comment: I recommend to use the class `scrartcl`. It is well documented in the documentation scrguide (German) or scrguien (English).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I tried looking for the English guide, but I got this message: *"Note: you requested the material at a path /macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf that doesn't exist. This is the closest directory."* Where is it?

Comment: @Alenanno: You can type `texdoc scrguien`

Comment: @Alenanno You surely can say `texdoc scrguien` on your system. However, the question, in the present form, doesn't seem to be answerable because it's too broad.

Comment: @egreg I was asking if there was an official manual, how is that broad? The answer is either "Yes here it is" or "No, there isn't one" or at worst "No there isn't one, but here is an alternative source...".

Comment: @egreg I could change it in order to ask only for those two things I mentioned.

Comment: @Alenanno your address for the doc on the web is out of date: try mirror.ctan.org:/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf

Comment: For such things, ConTeXt beats LaTeX hands down. All commands are designed with easy configurability in mind. So, you can middle align all section heads by saying `\setuphead[alternative=middle]`, decrease the spacing between items by saying `\setupitemize[inbetween={\blank[small]}]`, etc.

Comment: @Aditya yet another argument that drives me towards ConTeXt!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For customizing sectional units you can use the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package (for relatively "minor" changes) or the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; for customizing list-like environments, you can use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package; both `enumitem` and `titlesec` are very well documented and the documentations include numerous examples. Here's a little example illustrating the changes you mentioned in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\Large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\centering\bfseries\large}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=-1mm}

\begin{document}

\section{A test numbered section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{A test numbered subsection}
\subsection*{A test unnumbered subsection}
\section*{A test unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above approach applies mostly to standard document classes (`book`, `article` and `report`); other classes (`memoir` or the ones from the `KOMA-Script` bundle) have their own mechanisms; it should be noted, for example, that `memoir` or the `KOMA-Script` classes and `titlesec` are incompatible (See [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954) and [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954)).

Just for completeness's sake, I'll add one possible solution to both problems mentioned in the question but using the `memoir` document class. As I said before,  now it's not advisable to use `titlesec` to customize the sectional unit headings, but to use the features provided by the class; I used the `article` class option and the prdedefined `crosshead` chapter style to get centered titles for sections (now produced using `\chapter`) and used `\setsecheadstyle` to center the subsection titles (now produced using `\section`); `enumitem` is still used to customize the `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\chapterstyle{crosshead}
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\bfseries\large}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=-1mm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test numbered section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
\section{A test numbered subsection}
\section*{A test unnumbered subsection}
\chapter*{A test unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `scrartcl` from the `KOMA-Script` bundle, again using `titlesec` is not advisable, but you could use `\sectfont` instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand\sectfont{\centering\bfseries}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=-1mm}

\begin{document}

\section{A test numbered section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{A test numbered subsection}
\subsection*{A test unnumbered subsection}
\section*{A test unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As I used `\sectfont`, the changes will also affect subsubsections.

Finally, if you want to apply the changes to the `amsart` document class, you will only have to change the subsection formatting (section titles are centered by deafault in this class); the change can be done by redefining `\subsection` as implemented in `amsart.cls`, or using `titlesec` (as in the first example since `titlesec` is compatible with the AMS-family of document classes), or by patching this command with the help of, for example, the `etoolbox` package. A little example (lists have a more tight vertical spacing in this class so I left the modification commented):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
\makeatother
%\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=-1mm}

\begin{document}

\section{A test numbered section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{A test numbered subsection}
\subsection*{A test unnumbered subsection}
\section*{A test unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The list command is not working, weird... I am using `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` if it means something.

Comment: @Alenanno using the `shortlabels` option is not the cause of the problem (at least not with my example code); most probably you are using an outdated version of `enumitem`; the old syntax used `\setenumerate`, but this command is now deprecated and you should use the code as I posted it in my example. This is my version of enumitem (for comparison purposes): `enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists`. If outdated packages was not the problem, please edit your question adding a minimal, complete version of the problematic code.

Comment: Err I hate to be a newbie, but where do I check the package version? :D Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Alenanno Add `\listfiles` somewhere in the *preamble* of your document; the only purpose of this command is to write a list of the files used and their versions in the output console and in the `.log` file. Process your document and then open the `.log` file and search for the section  `*File List*`.

Comment: Oh, yes mine is v2.2... Maybe I should update all of my packages. :)

Comment: @Alenanno indeed! ;-) I've updated my answer showing a solution using `memoir`; if I have time I will also provide some code with `scrartcl`.

Comment: @Alenanno I added some code for `scrartcl` and `amsart`.